# How can I get URL of JS file in same JS file?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is my script src URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url)

I have situation:

```
<script 
  type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://server/some.js">
</script>
```

In file **some.js** I need to know full path of same file **some.js**, eq. **"http://server/some.js"**. How can I do this?

I can't change HTML code (clients are including JS file).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try that one

```
sc = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

for(idx = 0; idx < sc.length; idx++)
{
  s = sc.item(idx);

  if(s.src && s.src.match(/some\.js$/))
  { return s.src; }
}
```

Comment: Tomasz, am I missing something or where do you initialise sc? Also, IMO the whole thing is cleaner if you add the var keyword before 
    idx = 0
and s. Nice piece of code, otherwise.

Comment: Tom Bartel - you were right
fixed and thx for the tip on that

Comment: without `var idx=0` in the for loop you will introduce a global idx variable (unless you previously defined `idx` with `var`)

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is just to look for the last script to be added to the document:

```
var scripts= document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var mysrc= scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
```

This has to be done in the main body of the script, not in code called later. Preferably do it at the start of the script and remember the variable so it can be used in later function calls if necessary, and so it's not affected by code later in the script inserting any new `<script>` nodes into the document.

Comment: Does this with with the async attribute too?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works in all browsers, by try this:

```
function getScriptFileName() {
  return (new Error).fileName;
}
```

Comment: Sadly no, the `Error` object is unstandardised and `fileName` only seems to exist in Mozilla.

Comment: Seems does not work in Safari.