# Can I get the location of where a JavaScript library is loaded from, from within the script?

Tags: javascript, dom

Lets say I have a page with this code on it on www.foo.com:

```
<script src="http://www.bar.com/script.js" />
```

Can I write code from within script.js that can check that it was served from bar.com?  Obviously document.location.href would give me foo.com.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url/984656#984656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

give you a collection of all the scripts in the page
After this you can read their src property to find your target (I hope you know how the script is called)

```
for (var i=0, limit=scripts.lenght; i< limit; i++) {
    if (scripts[i].src.substr(<calculate your offset>) == scriptName) {
       // Have you found your script, extract your data
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't tell if script.js is being __served__ from www.bar.com, just that the src was that. It doesn't account for redirects.

Comment: Let's say it is a good starting point, though. You can dig further with a xhttprequest if you need to investigate redirection too.

Comment: I think this is probably the best answer, given I know the scriptname.  Seems like the bit I was really hoping for isn't available client-side, but this is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find out the location of a non-worker script is the non-standard `error.fileName`, which is only supported by Firefox and Opera:

```
var loc = (new Error).fileName;
```

If the script is a worker thread (which of course it isn't), then you could just use the `location` object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really important, you could work around it by defining a string containing the script URL in front of each script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">SCRIPT_URL = "http://www.bar.com/script.js"</script>
<script src="http://www.bar.com/script.js" />
```

Inside the script file you can then access the URL

```
alert("my URL is "+SCRIPT_URL);
```

Not too elegant but should work.

You could also, if you have a server-side language like PHP and don't mind sending JS files through the interpreter (Big performance caveat!), do something like this within the JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var my_url = "<? echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>"</script>
```

but that should really, really be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your script in a condition, kind of like an adult diaper, if you insist.

```
if(top.location.host==='www.bar.com'){
//the whole script goes here
}

else alert('Nyah Nyah Nyah!')
```

Comment: I want the script to load, no matter where it's being hosted (it's going to be DNS CNAME'd from a bunch of hosts) I just need to track where it's being served from so it can create URLs to resources on it's own domain.