# What are some arugments for/against using jQuery.getScript()?

Tags: jquery

I'm considering using this jquery utility as a possible solution, but I want to have a better understanding of it's use. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you may need to be more specific in what you want to use it for and what other solutions you are thinking of implementing. In general, the function loads a script via AJAX and then executes it. Is fetching a script something that you need to do, or can you organise your code in a manner that doesn't require scripts to be fetched via a GET request to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you really want to know, but in essence:

- It makes an (XMLHttp)request.
- After that, it just creates an `<script>` node in the document (head, as far as I remember)
- and sets the text of that script node to the contents of the response that it got from the request.

I struggled with debugging scripts included from the same domain in Firebug. Their source seem to vanish in the pits of `jQuery.globalEval()`.  They work, they are certainly evaluated - it is just that globalEval seems to clear up everything after itself so debugging is near impossible. Also, [some people seem to miss the ability to peek at the src attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277978/get-the-url-of-currently-executing-js-file-when-dynamically-loaded/2300932#2300932).