# getting the path of a javascript file

Tags: javascript, absolute-path, src

In a javascript file (e.g. script.js) I need a variable that contains the absolute path to this file.

How can I do this dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255689/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-the-currenctly-executing-javascript-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255689/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-the-currenctly-executing-javascript-code) (genius, didn't know this was possible at all!) should yield the full URL to the file. This will work only when the script is included traditionally using a `script` tag, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to same question:

[What is my script src URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url/984656#984656)

in above link they suggest to use also

```
scripts[scripts.length-1].getAttribute('src', -1)
```

I don't know why, but you might better investigate it a bit.