# Get URL to JS file

Tags: jquery, path

How am I able to get the full path to the functions.js file on my site in the functions.js-file?

Example: My JS file is in the following folder
/wp-content/themes/example/js/functions.js

I want via jQuery pull the full path:
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/functions.js

Comment: are you looking for `window.location.href`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255689/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-the-currently-executing-javascript-code

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.origin` will provide the domain part of the URL. Then you can append your path.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

For example:

```
// Prints "http://stackoverflow.com"
console.log(window.location.origin);
```

Comment: I need the exact path down to the level:  http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/ this because the theme name can be changed.

Comment: Where does the theme name come from? You could pass that down into the Javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.location.hostname` to return your hostname. For example, if you would run it on SO, its value would be `stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

**alert(document.URL);**

[Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)