# Retrieve the current javascript file name and line number

Tags: javascript, introspection, ecmascript-5

Is there a standard way of accessing the current file name of a script?

Is there something like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in [C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__FILE__.html) or [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

If there is no standard way of doing this, what are the tools that would allow to add such functionality to .js files (preprocessing)?

I am not looking for [browser specific solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255727/171711) (i.e. **`ReferenceError: document is not defined`**)

Comment: No, there is no standard way to do this, as it's mainly condsidered useless, and when you need the filename of the current file in your code, 99% of the time you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that inside javascript, but it would be easy to implement by injecting a variable server side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're using, but in node.js you can do it like this

**file.js**

```
var path = require("path");
console.log(path.basename(__filename));
// => file.js
```

---

There's **no** way to do this in the browser though.

Comment: Most of the time the scripts are used outside of node.js, but I can run most tests in node and benefit from this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using NodeJS you can use `__filename` or `module.filename`, however in the browser, no you can't.