# How to get the javascript file path at run-time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, callback, callstack

Requirement:
I want to find all the backbone views (src file path) used to develop an existing page. In our case each back-view will be maintained in a separate js file. In a nutshell I want to find the js files path (views which are extending Backbone view).

What I have tried:
I our case we have a wrapper view which is extending Backbone view, further all views will extends the wrapper view. So In the initialize method of wrapper-view I am generating error to get the call stack and further I am able to find the js-file-paths.

```
var WrapperView = Backbone.View.extend({        
initialize: function() {
    this.track();
},
track : function() {
    try{
        throw new Error("STACK");
    }
    catch(e){
        this.$el.attr('view-url', e.stack.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/.*js*(?=(?:(?!http)[\s\S])*https?:\/\/\S*backbone-min\.js)/)[0]);
    }

    if(Object.observe){
        Object.observe(this, function(changes){
            var eleProp = _.filter(changes, function(prop){ return prop.name == "$el"; })[0];
            if(!eleProp) return;
            eleProp.object.$el.attr('view-url', j$(eleProp.oldValue).attr('view-url'));
        }, ["update"])
    }
}   
});

var ChildView = WrapperView.extend({
initialize: function() {
    WrapperView.prototype.initialize.apply(this);
    this.track();
}
});
```

Backbone will invoke ------> ChildView.initialize --------> WrapperView.initialize();

As the ChildView.initialize function call is in call stack, I can get the file path.

What I want:
Though above solution is working, I don't want to include my track logic in the WrapperView, as it may not guarantee that all child views will call the WrapperView.prototype.initialize and I don't want to touch the framework src. So to fix this I included the track logic in Backbone.View (Js plugin) itself instead of WrapperView.

```
(function(){
var _viewExtend = Backbone.View.extend;
var newExtend = function (protoProps, classProps) {
    var _init = protoProps.initialize;
    var newInit = function(){
        try{
            throw new Error("STACK");
        }
        catch(e){
            this.$el.attr('view-url', e.stack.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/.*js*(?=(?:(?!http)[\s\S])*https?:\/\/\S*backbone-min\.js)/)[0]);
        }

        if(Object.observe){
            Object.observe(this, function(changes){
                var eleProp = _.filter(changes, function(prop){ return prop.name == "$el"; })[0];
                if(!eleProp) return;
                eleProp.object.$el.attr('view-url', j$(eleProp.oldValue).attr('view-url'));
            }, ["update"]);
        }
        return _init.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    protoProps.initialize = newInit; 
    return _viewExtend.call(this, protoProps, classProps);
};
Backbone.View.extend = newExtend;
})();
```

But the call stack not included the childview file path as the no call got made from child-view, so please help me to find a way get the things done.

Backbone will invoke ------> newInit (stack generated here) --------> Childview.initialize();

Note: If any other approach is there to achieve the requirement, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the file-path of the currently executing javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255689/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-the-currently-executing-javascript-code)

Comment: @PaulSweatte Nope, this is a different scenario. I have a function pointer from that I want to know the function src js file path. Similar to how chrome dev tool shows the file path with line number from function pointer (reference)