# document.currentScript is null

Tags: javascript

Browser is Chrome, `document.currentScript` should be supported but

`index.html`

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="1.js"></script>
<style>
```

`1.js`

```
setInterval(function() {
  var fullUrl = document.currentScript.src;
  console.log(fullUrl)
},2000)
```

```
Error : 
1.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`document.currentScript` only [returns the script that is currently being processed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript#Notes).  During callbacks and events, the script has finished being processed and `document.currentScript` will be `null`.  This is intentional, as keeping the reference alive would prevent the script from being garbage collected if it's removed from the DOM and all other references removed.

If you need to keep a reference to the script outside of any callbacks, you can:

```
var thisScript = document.currentScript;

setInterval(() => console.log(thisScript.src), 2000);
```

Comment: Just be sure to do this in a closure to isolate `thisScript`.

Comment: If it's the `src` value you're after, then why not just save that value, instead of the whole Script object from the DOM?
`var thisScriptSrc = document.currentScript && document.currentScript.src;`

Comment: I have code executing inside a constructor method that attempts to save the src attribute into a local variable. In certain cases, WHEN IT IS EXECUTING, document.currentScript is reported to be NULL. This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Any idea how to capture it in a react/tsx project?

Answer (score 9):

`document.currentScript` will also be null if script was loaded as a module like this.

```
<script type="module" src="foo/bar.js"></script>
```

For modules, docs say `import.meta.url` should be used.

Comment: `import.meta.url` does not contain script elements.

Answer (score 7):

You can keep the reference of `document.currentScript` outside the callback

```
var currentScript = document.currentScript;

setInterval(function(){
    var fullUrl = currentScript.src;
    console.log(fullUrl)
},2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript), which says:

> It's important to note that this will not reference the `<script>` element if the code in the script is being called as a callback or event handler; it will only reference the element while it's initially being processed.

Comment: @Brian: Look again.