# How to get query parameter from the script source?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I do

```
<script src="myscripts.js?query=123"></script>
```

is there a way to get the `query` parameter from `myscripts.js`?

Comment: This doesn't work like query parameters to a URL.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I know. For the lack of a better word, I used that. I'm wondering if it is possible to pass any data from the script url to the script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag

Comment: Technically first you get the URL, then just parse as needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255727/3684265

Comment: If you want to make a value available for your script, you could just declare it globally. Better yet, pass an argument to a function in `myscripts.js`.