# Relative fetch or XHR in a UI-Less Outlook add-in on Windows

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am making an Outlook add-in with UI-Less `LaunchEvent`-based parts. In order to run on Windows, I have to use Outlook's Javascript runtime, **so I have to make do without `window` or `document`**.

At some point I have to fetch some data from the add-in's server. I tried using both Fetch and XHR to no avail.

Naive example with Fetch:

```js
fetch("/JsonData").then(r => r.json());
```

However, this results in a `TypeError: Network request failed`. Additionally, I am using Wireshark, and I see no request sent to the server.

Note that:

- I am in a [Javascript-only runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtimes#javascript-only-runtime), so no `window` or `document`
- I have no control over the server root URL so I cannot hardcode it
- I have tried several tricks based on Javascript's stacktrace to get the current JS file URL, without success (best I got was `code` as the file URL [using this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319494/4482039))

How can I use a relative URL to retrieve data from my server? This is such a common thing to do that I am sure there is a way to do it, just not the way I am doing it.

**EDIT** It appears that [marking the add-in for debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch#mark-your-add-in-for-debugging) allows Fetch to work as expected with the exact same statement as above, even when no debugger is attached. This means enabling add-in debbugging changes something in the runtime that allows Fetch to target the add-in's own server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when making calls outside the domain your add-in is hosted in, you need to specify those domains in your add-in's manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://siteone.com/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://sitetwo.com/</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Second, the same-origin policy enforced by the browser prevents a script loaded from one domain from getting or manipulating properties of a webpage from another domain. This means that, by default, the domain of a requested URL must be the same as the domain of the current webpage. For example, this policy will prevent a webpage in one domain from making XmlHttpRequest web-service calls to a domain other than the one where it is hosted.

Because Office Add-ins are hosted in a browser control, the same-origin policy applies to script running in their web pages as well.

The same-origin policy can be an unnecessary handicap in many situations, such as when a web application hosts content and APIs across multiple subdomains. There are a few common techniques for securely overcoming same-origin policy enforcement. The [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article can only provide the briefest introduction to some of them.

Comment: I already tried adding `localhost` to the AppDomains list, without success. Besides, I don't think this is a same-origin problem, because I don't specify a domain in the Fetch URL. Also, I have a task pane with the exact same Fetch calls that work perfectly well, so the problem is specific to Outlook's Javascript-only runtime.

Comment: I see. In that case I'd suggest posting it as an issue to the Office-JS repo at github.