# JavaScript - How do I get the URL of script being called?

Tags: javascript

I include myscript.js in the file `http://site1.com/index.html` like this:

```
<script src=http://site2.com/myscript.js></script>
```

Inside "myscript.js", I want to get access to the URL "http://site2.com/myscript.js".  I'd like to have something like this:

```
function getScriptURL() {
    // something here
    return s
}

alert(getScriptURL());
```

Which would alert "http://site2.com/myscript.js" if called from the index.html mentioned above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is my script src URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might I get the script filename from within that script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script)

Comment: Based on your example URLs, you may want to note what behavior you're expecting if the browser is set to block third party scripts.

Comment: To Exact Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called/67235905#67235905

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var index = scripts.length - 1;
var myScript = scripts[index];
```

The variable `myScript` now has the script dom element. You can get the src url by using `myScript.src`.

Note that this needs to execute as part of the initial evaluation of the script. If you want to not pollute the Javascript namespace you can do something like:

```
var getScriptURL = (function() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var index = scripts.length - 1;
    var myScript = scripts[index];
    return function() { return myScript.src; };
})();
```

Comment: Will this always return the URL of the right script though, in all browsers?  This looks like it will return the last script tag, but what if the document has more than one script tag in it?

Comment: The code needs to run in the global context of the script and then you need to cache the value somewhere if you need it later on in the script. If you are using the module pattern to do information hiding, your getScriptURL function could be defined in each script.

Comment: Ok...my question then becomes, do all browsers always fully load an execute the complete contents of a remote script before moving on to the next script tag?  How rigorously is this standardized?  I could imagine it happening in parallel...

Comment: It is required that scripts run completely and in order because of what would happen if the script tag contained a document.write. This is the reason for the recommendations to put scripts at the bottom of the page because they will actually block other content from loading. 

That said, HTML5 modifies that with the use of the async and defer attributes: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#script

Comment: Further to the scripts at bottom, here is the Yahoo! best practices on that: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: @lambacck: it might be worth noting that `myScript.src` returns full http path of the script only if a full http path is written in `src`. Otherwise on IE6 and IE7 a relative path is returned. On all other browsers including IE8 a full http path is always returned, even if in code it's written a relative path. If interested in more details see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3865126/260080

Comment: This doesn't work if you load the script after the page has loaded using something like this:

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);`

Comment: @Seanonymous It probably would if you appended it to the body instead.

Comment: I have come across a case where this algorithm doesn't work reliably. Other script tags that are set to async can run between your script being requested and run. These scripts can add other scripts to the DOM which appear after yours. When your script run the last script on the page is no longer yours and the wrong `src` is returned.

Comment: @Karl is the script you are trying to run this on also async or just the other scripts?

Comment: @lambacck Just the other script is running async. Mine is still synchronous.

Comment: Does not work with non script tag scripts. What if i'm using require.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script

Btw this url works even when imported from html imports.
Your way does not work with that.

Maybe update the comment to point at a much better way?

Comment: This does not work for me in Firefox. But the method by pery mimon works.

Comment: program should be agnostic enough to have correct result of all scenarios.  you cannot assume that your script is in the head section and it is the last script in the list.

Comment: Doesn't work if the script is loaded with `defer` and there's also INLINE scripts on the page, like `<script> //some code </script>`

Comment: Note that .src can return an absolute path, even if a relative path was specified. You can use .getAttribute('src')

Comment: Can confirm this does *NOT* work 100% reliably even if your own script is not marked as `async` or `defer`. Sometimes it will return the source of a different script.

Answer (score 68):

Everything except IE supports

```
document.currentScript
```

Eg

```
document.currentScript.src
```

Comment: More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: More precisely: `document.currentScript.src`.

Comment: A word of caution! it will not work if the loaded is script type is module. for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called/67235905#67235905

Answer (score 61):

You can add id attribute to your script tag (even if it is inside a head tag):

```
<script id="myscripttag" src="http://site2.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

and then access to its src as follows:

```
document.getElementById("myscripttag").src
```

of course id value should be the same for every document that includes your script, but I don't think it is a big inconvenience for you.

Comment: This answer should be marked as "accepted" as it covers the cases when you call the method not in the "global" script context or in "async" script, and it doesn't depend on the browser implementation.

Comment: Note that `.src` can return an absolute path, even if a relative path was specified. You can use `.getAttribute('src')`

Answer (score 27):

Simple and straightforward solution that work very well :

If it not IE you can use `document.currentScript`
For IE you can do `document.querySelector('script[src*="myscript.js"]')`
so :

```
function getScriptURL(){
 var script =  document.currentScript || document.querySelector('script[src*="myscript.js"]')
 return script.src
}
```

###### update

In a module script, you can use:

```
 import.meta.url
```

as describe in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta#using_import.meta)

Answer (score 20):

I wrote a class to find get the path of scripts that works with delayed loading and async script tags.

I had some template files that were relative to my scripts so instead of hard coding them I made created the class to do create the paths automatically. [The full source is here on github.](https://github.com/QueueHammer/codecraftsman.js/blob/master/codecraftsman.js)

A while ago I had use arguments.callee to try and do something similar but I recently read on the MDN that it is [not allowed in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee).

```
function ScriptPath() {
  var scriptPath = '';
  try {
    //Throw an error to generate a stack trace
    throw new Error();
  }
  catch(e) {
    //Split the stack trace into each line
    var stackLines = e.stack.split('\n');
    var callerIndex = 0;
    //Now walk though each line until we find a path reference
    for(var i in stackLines){
      if(!stackLines[i].match(/http[s]?:\/\//)) continue;
      //We skipped all the lines with out an http so we now have a script reference
      //This one is the class constructor, the next is the getScriptPath() call
      //The one after that is the user code requesting the path info (so offset by 2)
      callerIndex = Number(i) + 2;
      break;
    }
    //Now parse the string for each section we want to return
    pathParts = stackLines[callerIndex].match(/((http[s]?:\/\/.+\/)([^\/]+\.js)):/);
  }

  this.fullPath = function() {
    return pathParts[1];
  };

  this.path = function() {
    return pathParts[2];
  };

  this.file = function() {
    return pathParts[3];
  };

  this.fileNoExt = function() {
    var parts = this.file().split('.');
    parts.length = parts.length != 1 ? parts.length - 1 : 1;
    return parts.join('.');
  };
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Works more reliably since it relies on the stack trace which will always list the correct precedence of executed scripts.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but I was trying this code snippet and found that the part where it adds 2 to the current index in the for loop "callerIndex = Number(i) + 2;" seems to break be unnecessary and causes it to not work. Simply eliminating the "+ 2" has it working. Is there something I am misinterpreting or some other scenario that that + 2 would be necessary for?

Comment: you don't need to throw "Error" this way ( to get it's ".stack" ) it is just an object like others: console.log( new Error().stack );

Comment: Thanks for this idea, and thanks to @AbdullahAydın for the idea of preventing a throw. Then I guess the following one-liner would do the trick, wouldn't it?   var scriptUrl = new Error().stack.match(/@(https?:\/\/.+):\d+:\d+/)[1]

Comment: Also @Pierre-Antoine keep in mind that Error.prototype.stack property is non-standard :/ you should use it with care. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack#Quick_Links

Comment: @AbdullahAydın: Note that the stack property of a new error is *not* populated in the IE and Edge browsers until the error is thrown.

Comment: Also note that IE9 (if you care about it) does not have the stack property at all, even when the error is thrown.

Answer (score 15):

if you have a chance to use jQuery, the code would look like this:

```
$('script[src$="/myscript.js"]').attr('src');
```

Comment: Does it work with defer, async and lazy loading scripts?

Comment: It's just looking through the DOM for a script tag with the src "/myscript.js". other attributes won't matter

Comment: To use this with wordpress to in any other place that appends the version you should use $('script[src*="/myscript.js"]').attr('src'); this way it will ignore the ?ver=2.3.3 at the end of the script. The * will keep it working regardless of what is at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Following code lets you find the script element with given name

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
        var len = scripts.length
        for(var i =0; i < len; i++) {
            if(scripts[i].src.search("<your JS file name") > 0 && scripts[i].src.lastIndexOf("/") >= 0) {
                absoluteAddr = scripts[i].src.substring(0, scripts[i].src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems that using querySelector() would be a bit shorter and probably quicker nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.currentScript.src
```

will return the URL of the current Script URL.

**Note:** If you have loaded the script with type `Module` then use

```
import.meta.url
```

for more [import.meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) & [currentScript.src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Answer (score 0):

Some necromancy, but here's a function that tries a few methods

```js
function getScriptPath (hint) {
    if (  typeof document === "object" && 
          typeof document.currentScript === 'object' && 
          document.currentScript && // null detect
          typeof document.currentScript.src==='string' && 
          document.currentScript.src.length > 0) {
        return document.currentScript.src;
    }
    
    
    let here = new Error();
    if (!here.stack) {
        try { throw here;} catch (e) {here=e;}
    }
    if (here.stack) {
        
        const stacklines = here.stack.split('\n');
        console.log("parsing:",stacklines);
        let result,ok=false;
        stacklines.some(function(line){
            if (ok) {
               const httpSplit=line.split(':/');
               const linetext = httpSplit.length===1?line.split(':')[0]:httpSplit[0]+':/'+( httpSplit.slice(1).join(':/').split(':')[0]);
               const chop = linetext.split('at ');
               if (chop.length>1) {
                   result = chop[1];
                   if ( result[0]!=='<') {
                      console.log("selected script from stack line:",line);               
                      return true;
                   }
                   result=undefined;
               }
               return false; 
            }
            ok = line.indexOf("getScriptPath")>0;
            return false;
        });
        return result;
    }
    
    if ( hint && typeof document === "object") {
       const script = document.querySelector('script[src="'+hint+'"]');
       return script && script.src && script.src.length && script.src;
    }
    
}
   
   console.log("this script is at:",getScriptPath ())
```

Answer (score -6):

Can't you use location.href or location.host and then append the script name?

Comment: That won't work, because the script is running within the http://site1.com/index.html page.  So, even through the script is loaded from site2.com, if you access location from within the script, it will return "http://site1.com/index.html"...

Comment: Previous comment might not make it clear enough, but location.href is the URL of current page. The script will probably be located in some sub-directory like /scripts/script.js or could even be an external one. If there is a need to get the URL of the current script, then there is generally a serious reason for that and it really and simple page URL will not be of any help.