# Javascript - what's my URL?

Tags: javascript, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How might I get the script filename from within that script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script)
>   [JavaScript - How do I get the URL of script being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called)

How, within my javascript code, can I determine the URL the javascript was loaded from, e.g. if I have a page http://www.example.com/index.html

```
<html>
<script src='/code/whereami.js'></script>
...
```

Then my javascipt would be loaded from http://www.example.com/code/whereami.js but how do find this URL *from within* the code?

(yes, by definition, as the programmer, I should know where my files are - the point of the exercise here is to verify the integrity of the resulting page)

Comment: i guess u can get that from meta type and not url ??!

Comment: The proposed duplicates do provide a limited solution: but rely on the script beig executed sychrnously with its declaration - which is not exactly ideal.