# cUrl parsing php

Tags: php, parsing, curl, google-analytics

In my site I had a Google Analytics Universal tracking code, which generates a some request go google .gif file with this parameters:

[image]

How can I parse all parameters from ***Query String Parameters*** or just all of parameters which a requested from .gif file cUrl?

URL example:

```
curl 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j16&a=589794211&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fmellowkids.ru%2Fserv-ga%2Ftest.php%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_term%3Dkeyword%26utm_content%3Dadstext%26utm_campaign%3Dcampaignname&ul=ru&de=UTF-8&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1563x436&je=1&fl=12.0%20r0&_u=MAC~&cid=1374804136.1392407945&tid=UA-44059933-1&z=743339889' -H 'Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Referer: http://mellowkids.ru/serv-ga/test.php?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=keyword&utm_content=adstext&utm_campaign=campaignname' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36' --compressed
```

Comment: could you explain, why you need to parse this string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function.

Comment: i'm newbie in php, can you write a simple code, how a can parse this cUrl?

Comment: Explode past ? and run the query string through parse_str. Use var_dump to debug.

Comment: I do not understand how I pick up (grab) this link from the browser (from DOM). How to parse it through parse_str, not so important.

Comment: You could check what scripts are being called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called

Comment: I dont understand code in your link. If i visit my test page mellowkids.ru/serv-ga/test.php Google Analytics will make a cUrl request to his .gif file (You can see it in the Developer Tools in Chrome). How i can grab this curl, put in variable and prin it via echo()?

Comment: basically, Google Analytics takes all parameters from this string from client. It means, that you can get this parameters like user browser, browser language or something else directly from the user. So what parameters do you need?