# JavaScript : Get the GET request parameter in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called), I would like to get the GET request parameter, but in the script tag itself.

My script tag in HTML `<head>` is:

```
<script src="js/script.js?lang=en"></script>
```

How can I get the `lang` value ?

jQuery is used and I can obtain the `src` by:

```
$('script[src$="/script.js"]').attr('src');
```

Comment: you found the answer quickly.

Comment: @DanielLisik I guess, he knew the answer before typing this question. and he is trying to help future referrers.

Comment: You could also use `data-lang="en"`

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue after few tries, and I think somebody may find it useful.

Comment: One thing about `data-lang` is that it is only valid in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the parameters in `<script>` tag, we can use:

```
var lang;
var src = $('script[src~="js/script.js"]').attr('src');
if(src != undefined) {
  lang = src.split("lang=")[1] ? src.split("lang=")[1] : 'yourDefaultValue';
}
```

Comment: Think you probably want `src~="js/script.js"`