# get javascript file path

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, filepath

In my html code:

```
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "elements/effects/my_js_code.js"></script>
</head>
```

In elements/effects/js/my_js_code.js:

```
function ($) { $('head').append("<link type = 'text/css' rel =
'stylesheet' href = 'elements/effects/css/my_js_code.css'>"); /* more
code */ }
```

how to detect the full path of my_js_code.js from my_js_code.js?

```
function ($) { $('head').append("<link type = 'text/css' rel =
'stylesheet' href = '" + MY_FUNC_CALCULATE_PATH("../css/my_js_code.css") + "'>"); /* more
code */ }
```

Comment: do you have to work on old browsers ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called can be of help

Comment: parse `document.currentScript.src` to get the path info. you can use an `<a href=src>` to do that