# Get the current script src among multiple instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/test.js?addr=(address)"> </script
```

The address is different for each instance
I tried the answers from [What is my script src URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url) and [JavaScript - How do I get the URL of script being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called) but they always give the same source. Here is an example output from

`var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
 script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
console.log (script.getAttribute('src', -1))`

[image]

How can I get the actual source?

Comment: you mean like [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) ?

Comment: `$('script').each(function(){ console.log($(this).attr('src'));});`

Comment: I guess you can use this approach instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files

Answer (score 2):

If I understand clearly, what you want is [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) which will return the script element which is being parsed (beware, it will be null after first execution of the script, so you might want to do your url parsing synchronously) :

```html
<script id="find_me">
// replace 'id' with 'src' for your case
console.log(document.currentScript.id);
</script>
<script id="me_too">
console.log(document.currentScript.id);
</script>
<script id="and_even_from_remote" src="data:application/javascript,console.log(document.currentScript.id)"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the warning, I get null every time

Comment: @Joe, even in the snippet ? By the warning I mean you need to get it from when the script is being processed the first time, like I do here. If you call it again in an asynchronous function (e.g in a setTimeout, or in an Event, be it `window.onload`) then it will return null. But actually, with the same restrictions, `var s = document.querySelectorAll('script'); var yourScript = s[s.length - 1]` should do the same, since no other element would have been parsed since then.

Comment: I meant when I copied the code into mine I get null

Comment: @joe and when are calling it ? If it is in an event, like window.onload, or jquery equivalent, then it won't work.

Comment: It should run as soon as it is created. The script loads jquery first so it may be that is causing issues