# How to identify the origin JavaScript was loaded from, including redirects

Tags: javascript, browser, same-origin-policy

Is it possible to get the origin that a script tag was loaded from?

**Note**, I don't want the `src` of the script tag as that doesn't include redirection.

I have found post like [JavaScript - How do I get the URL of script being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called) but this are all based off identifying the script src rather than the origin the script was eventually loaded from

Comment: What do you mean with "origin"? the third server in the second rack in the datacenter in city xy?

Comment: @Piyush — I'm pretty sure the OP means "programmatically, with client-side JS"

Comment: @JonasWilms — It's a standard term: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin

Comment: @quentin but then the question is ... why? What usecase is the OP trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible.

The `src` is the only API provided. You can't even make a new HTTP request to it and find out that way since `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` follow redirects transparently.