# How to retrieve the URL of the curent remote script?

Tags: javascript

Here is my page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "//myremoteserver.com/chat.js"></script>

<script>
var chat = new Chat();
</script>
```

How can I retrieve the url of the script inside the Chat class?

(answer : //myremoteserver.com/chat.js)

I tried:

**window.location.origin**; gives me the url of the current page
**document.getElementsByTagName('script')** : do not provide url

Comment: have you tried `document.getElementsByTagName('script').src` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - How do I get the URL of script being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976651/javascript-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-script-being-called)

Comment: You woon't be able to find out _which_ of the included scripts is running the code through code, as JS treats it all as a single big script and just adds more to the end. Its not aware of which file the code resided in through JS itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by going through `<head>`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the script an id

```
<script id = "myScript" src = "//myremoteserver.com/chat.js"></script>
var element = document.getElementById('myScript');
console.log(element.src);
```

Can't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 ways to do this :

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].getAttribute("src"));
console.log(document.scripts[1].src);
```

```html
<script src= "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```