# Javascript: with any Firefox plugin (Firebug, whatever), how to see the route from a .js has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, firefox

with any Firefox plugin (Firebug, whatever), how to see the route from a .js has been loaded?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Huh? Does that make sense to yourself? And please don't write the entire question in the title.

Comment: Gee whiz, people, the guy didn't even get a chance to clarify what "route" is supposed to mean.  Not everybody writes flawless English on their first try.

Comment: @klausbyskov @Pointy Yeah, I agree this was way too quickly closed. Sorry @OP (but work on that question!) Voting to reopen

Comment: Also voted to reopen. I'd guess user248959 was meaning to ask how to find out what URL a .js file was loaded from (rather than the network route, for example).

Comment: @Mark "route" could also refer to URL rewriting... It's incredibly hazy

Comment: Hopefully, he'll come back and update the question.

Comment: I can't in good conscience vote to re-open this, as it's not at all clear what's being asked. However, you might find one or more of the following helpful: [What is my script src URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url), [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: Adding a vote to reopen this. I suspect he wants to trace back a function (in which he probably has an alert/error) and see where it is called from.

Answer (score 2):

The [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) Firefox plugin lets you see all the HTTP transactions.  That would tell you the URL from which Javascript (and CSS and image, etc) files are loaded. The route taken by individual packets is not going to be available from any tool.

Comment: The Web Inspector available from the Develop menu in Safari shows the path that each script was loaded from in the Scripts pane.