# Javascript: with any Firefox plugin (Firebug, whatever), how to see the path from which a .js has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

with any Firefox plugin (Firebug, whatever), how to see the path from a .js has been loaded?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Isn't that the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935844/javascript-with-any-firefox-plugin-firebug-whatever-how-to-see-the-route-fro)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the script tab of Firebug. Choose the script you want. Then right-click the partial URL and select Copy Location to put it on the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) will do that for you.