# Jquery Wordpress PHP image reference

Tags: php, jquery, facebox

I'm trying to reference a image that is in the same folder has the .js but call it on any page of my php/wordpress page.

So the .js is in 
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/includes/demo/facebox.js
and the image is on 
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/includes/demo/closinglabel.png

but I'm referencing the js in the front page and on other pages basically www.example.com.  This is basically a fix for facebox because it won't let me autoload while picking my hrefs.  Can in .js find the path to the current .js location?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend referencing the image with a site-relative URL (one that begins with a /) then the image should work on any page of any domain that you use, so long as the domain has the same file system paths or/and rewrite rules.

Also, an answer to your secondary question can be found here:
[What is my script src URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984510/what-is-my-script-src-url/984656#984656)