# How can I get the name of function inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

How is it possible to learn the name of function I am in?

The below code alerts 'Object'. But I need to know how to alert "Outer."

```
function Outer(){

    alert(typeof this);

}
```

Comment: I'm curious, under what circumstances would the name of the function you're in actually not the one written out in the code?

Comment: @bryantsai: `window[window.prompt('Function name:', '')] = function(){ alert(arguments.callee.name); };`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that you can do that :

```
var name = arguments.callee.toString();
```

For more information on this, take a look at [this article](http://www.seifi.org/javascript/javascript-arguments.html).

```
function callTaker(a,b,c,d,e){
  // arguments properties
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(arguments.length);
  console.log(arguments.callee);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  // Function properties
 console.log(callTaker.length);
  console.log(callTaker.caller);
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller.caller);
  console.log(callTaker.name);
  console.log(callTaker.constructor);
}

function callMaker(){
  callTaker("foo","bar",this,document);
}

function init(){
  callMaker();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately `arguments.callee` is deprecated, but since ECMA hasn't defined any substitute yet, this is the way to go.

Comment: @boldewyn: after more searching I saw that too. But while it's deprecated it still works in most browsers. And like you said, there's no alternative sooooo... ^^

Comment: @Boldewyn, `arguments.callee` is not just deprecated. When strict mode is enabled, accessing it would cause TypeError.

Comment: I'm not sure arguments.callee is deprecated.
Function.arguments and Function.arguments.callee are, but not the callee property of the arguments of a function.  


From MDC:- 

JavaScript 1.4: Deprecated callee as a property of Function.arguments, retained it as a property of a function's local arguments variable.

Answer (score 34):

This will work:

```
function test() {
  var z = arguments.callee.name;
  console.log(z);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As of ES6, you can use [`Function.prototype.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). This has the added benefit of working with arrow functions, since they do not have their own arguments object.

```
function logFuncName() {
  console.log(logFuncName.name);
}

const logFuncName2 = () => {
  console.log(logFuncName2.name);
};
```

Comment: What about not wanting to use the function's own name? Something like "this.name" where "this" means "this function" rather than "this class"?

Comment: They should have made it like `function.name` or `[this.function].name`

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to figure this out, so tried to make it very clear for rookies like me.

### Approach 1 - arguments.callee.name

This approach used to work, but now in ES6 Strict Mode it will fail. *Don't* use Approach 1.

```
//approach 1 - don't use
let functionName = arguments.callee.name;
console.log(functionName);
```

### Approach 2 - create a function and use caller.name

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript) works in the latest version of Javascript and will not fail in Strict Mode. Use Approach 2. There are 2 steps.

Step 1 - Create a function that uses caller.name to return the name of the function that called it. Add this function to your code:

```
function getFuncName() {
   return getFuncName.caller.name
}
```

Step 2 - Call your function when you need the name of the function your code is currently in.

```
    function iWantThisName() { 
      console.log(getFuncName())
    }
    
    iWantThisName() 
    // Logs: "iWantThisName"
```

Comment: caller.name and callee.name is deprecated as per official documentation.

Comment: @SDK4551 :( thanks. any alternatives you know of?

Comment: Error stack can be used to get the same.

Comment: Error `TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`

What went wrong? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_caller_or_arguments_usage