# In javascript, how do I find out the name of a function from within that function?

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the name of function inside a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161383/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-function-inside-a-javascript-function)

The title should make it clear.

Is it possible *from within a function* to determine the name of that function?

Basically, I'm adding some debugging code to a number of functions, and I'd like to be able to simply add the following line inside every function:

```
if (global_debugOn) alert("Processing function " + function-name);
```

How can I get 'function-name'?

Yes, obviously I could simply type in the function name (after all I'm typing in the whole `alert` bit), but that's a hassle to do, especially if there is a nice simple way of retrieving it dynamically. Plus, as function names change during development, I'd like to keep it up-to-date...

I hoped that maybe the `arguments` attribute might hold this (e.g. `arguments[0]`, like in C), but I couldn't get it to work. I'm not even sure if `arguments` works anyway.

Thanks!

Rory

Comment: Sorry, I searched for an answer before I posted - must have missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing is [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee), which actually returns the function itself, not the name.

The only other thing is [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller), which returns a string, but that is only in Mozilla and is not even supported there anymore.

One last option is to call `arguments.callee.toString()` .. but that will return the function declaration, not just the name.

Comment: So just call `arguments.callee.toString()` and parse it to display whatever you need? For example, trim it so everything after and including the first bracket is removed.

Comment: @Duracell the output of that `toString()` is implementation-dependent and may not even contain the function name. I've seen some return "`[object Function]`". It is not reliable.

Comment: Oh ok. Ouch. Looks like the best way the is to assign a name to the function as a member then.

Answer (score 0):

you can say arguments.callee.toString() and the name may be in there.  it won't if you declare the function anonymously, i.e. var f = function () {} as opposed to function f(){}

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunc() {
        var ownName = arguments.callee.toString();
        ownName = ownName.substr('function '.length);
        ownName = ownName.substr(0, ownName.indexOf('('));
        alert(ownName);
}

someFunc();
```

Comment: or in a line-

String(arguments.callee).split('(')[0];