# How to get the function name from within that function?

Tags: javascript, function

How can I access a function name from inside that function?

```
// parasitic inheritance
var ns.parent.child = function() {
  var parent = new ns.parent();
  parent.newFunc = function() {

  }
  return parent;
}

var ns.parent = function() {
  // at this point, i want to know who the child is that called the parent
  // ie
}

var obj = new ns.parent.child();
```

Comment: well, in the parent, i can then access other functions by convention, such as ns[child][schema] or ns[child][dbService].

Without it, I have to hard code these references in every child class.

Comment: why not just pass the child function as an argument to the parent?
var parent = new ns.parent(this);

Comment: because there are dozens of such lookups, and dozens of children.  That is currently what I'm doing, but it's the same every time and would be perfect if that duplicate logic could simply be placed inside the parent once, based on the derived function.

Comment: see, it's not the child function I want, it's the naming convention used, because that naming convention can be used to load other functions that are not currently defined on the child object, but are related to that child throughout the system.

Comment: ie, 

app.schemas.child = {

}

which is defined in another file and not present on the child object.

Comment: @Scott `var ns.parent.child` - this code is invalid

Comment: @Scott, there is a lot going on here. Why do you need a reference back to the caller? Would it not be easier to send the reference while making the call?

Comment: what would you return if your function was defined as `foo = bar = function() { return function_name(); }`?

Comment: @Scott I agree with everyone else, your managing your complexity and code structure wrong to need to do this. This kind of hard-coupling is a bad design decision and is going to make a mess. @SimeVidas your a great necromancer :)

Comment: It strikes me has something odd, because if I do something like
var test2 = test;

What is the name of the function now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current function name in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435450/get-current-function-name-in-strict-mode)

Comment: It depends on lexical scope, you may find it by playing a little bit in this way `arguments.callee.caller ... .name`

Answer (score 214):

In ES6, you can just use `myFunction.name`.

Note: Beware that **some JS minifiers might throw away function names**, to compress better; you may need to tweak their settings to avoid that.

In ES5, the best thing to do is:

```
function functionName(fun) {
  var ret = fun.toString();
  ret = ret.substr('function '.length);
  ret = ret.substr(0, ret.indexOf('('));
  return ret;
}
```

Using `Function.caller` is non-standard. `Function.caller` and `arguments.callee` are both forbidden in strict mode.

Edit: nus's regex based answer below achieves the same thing, but has better performance!

Comment: While this didn't answer the question sufficiently for me (due to anonymous functions), it did give me idea to do this: `fun.toString().substr(0, 100)` which for my needs will be enough to locate the function in question. So, thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: Nice, ES6 `myFunction.name` is perfect. Is this a preferred thing to do in ES6?

Comment: Yup `myFunction.name` is the best thing to do in ES6.

Comment: NB. myFunction.name also works with ES6 arrow functions (usually anonymous), if you assign them in an expression (e.g. `const myNamedFunction = () => { ...};`). Thanks @hughfdjackson: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31544156/396246

Comment: What's the point in `myFunction.name` if you type the function name? defeats the purpose of magic variables.

Comment: @adi518: not necessarily .. suppose you have any array of functions and you iterating over it, using for/foreach ..then `arr[index].name` will also work :)

Comment: Or maybe even `fun.toString().split('(')[0].split(' ')[1]` or even shorter `fun.toString().split(/[\(\s]/)[1]`

Comment: @adi518 It's not useless. If I'm renaming the function within my IDE, `myFunction.name` will also be updated. Sure, intelliJ supports renaming identifiers within strings, but that works a lot less consistently and will silently become outdated if somebody forgets to tick the "search in strings" option. `myFunction.name` is a slightly better choice than hardcoding the string.

Answer (score 184):

**ES6** (inspired by sendy halim's answer below):

```
myFunction.name
```

[Explanation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). As of 2015 works in nodejs and all major browsers except IE.

Note: On bound functions this will give "`bound <originalName>`". You will have to strip the "bound " if you want to get the original name.

---

**ES5** (inspired by Vlad's answer):

If you have a reference to the function, you can do:

```
function functionName( func )
{
    // Match:
    // - ^          the beginning of the string
    // - function   the word 'function'
    // - \s+        at least some white space
    // - ([\w\$]+)  capture one or more valid JavaScript identifier characters
    // - \s*        optionally followed by white space (in theory there won't be any here,
    //              so if performance is an issue this can be omitted[1]
    // - \(         followed by an opening brace
    //
    var result = /^function\s+([\w\$]+)\s*\(/.exec( func.toString() )

    return  result  ?  result[ 1 ]  :  '' // for an anonymous function there won't be a match
}
```

- I have not run unit tests on this, or verified implementation
  differences, but in principle it should work, if not leave a comment.
- Note: won't work on bound functions
- Note: that `caller` and `callee` are considered deprecated.

**[1]** *I include it here because it is legal and often enough syntax highlighting tools fail to take into account the white space between function name and parenthesis. On the other hand, I'm not aware of any implementation of .toString() that will include white space here, so that's why you can omit it.*

---

As an answer to the original question, I would drop parasitic inheritance and go for some more traditional OOP design patterns. I wrote a [TidBits.OoJs](https://github.com/najamelan/TidBits_Javascript_OoJs) to comfortably write OOP code in JavaScript with a feature set mimicking C++ (not yet complete, but mostly).

I see from the comments that you would like to avoid passing information `parent` needs to it's constructor. I must admit that traditional design patterns won't save you from that one though, since it is generally a considered a good thing to make your dependencies obvious and enforced.

I would also suggest to steer away from anonymous functions. They only make debugging and profiling a PITA because everything just shows up as "anonymous function", and there is no benefit to them that I'm aware of.

Comment: Nice RegEx! Here's a performance test showing that your code is the fastest in many cases. In general it seems that RegEx beats native JS by around 2x speed here on average. http://jsperf.com/get-function-name/2

Comment: @Tomasz Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that. A bound function is actually a new function that wraps your original function. The ecmascript standard § 19.2.3.2 defines that the name of the new function shall be "bound" + originalName. The toString method won't work on bound functions either... You will have to strip the word bound.

Comment: What's the point in myFunction.name if you type the function name? defeats the purpose of magic variables.

Comment: Note that if you're using React Native this may not work properly. I have a RN project I'm working on with expo version 36 and a component method's `.name` property was showing up as the string "value", no matter what it was called. Weirdly enough, while testing in the expo app it was fine, however, once compiled into a real application, it would crash silently.

Answer (score 89):

what you're doing is assigning unnamed function to a variable. you probably need named function expression instead ( http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ ).

```
var x = function x() {
    console.log( arguments.callee.name );
}
x();
```

however I'm not sure how much cross-browser that is; there's an issue with IE6 that makes you function's name leak to the outer scope. also, arguments.callee is kind of deprecated and will result in error if you're using `strict mode`.

Comment: This doesn't works on old versions of Safari browser.

Comment: `arguments.callee` is forbidden in strict mode, but who cares--> plus one.

Answer (score 27):

It looks like the most stupid thing, that I wrote in my life, but it's funny :D

```
function getName(d){
  const error = new Error();
  const firefoxMatch = (error.stack.split('\n')[0 + d].match(/^.*(?=@)/) || [])[0];
  const chromeMatch = ((((error.stack.split('at ') || [])[1 + d] || '').match(/(^|\.| <| )(.*[^(<])( \()/) || [])[2] || '').split('.').pop();
  const safariMatch = error.stack.split('\n')[0 + d];

  // firefoxMatch ? console.log('firefoxMatch', firefoxMatch) : void 0;
  // chromeMatch ? console.log('chromeMatch', chromeMatch) : void 0;
  // safariMatch ? console.log('safariMatch', safariMatch) : void 0;
  
  return firefoxMatch || chromeMatch || safariMatch;
}
```

`d` - depth of stack. `0` - return this function name, `1` - parent, etc.;
`[0 + d]` - just for understanding - what happens;
`firefoxMatch` - works for safari, but I had really a little time for testing, because mac's owner had returned after smoking, and drove me away :'(

Testing:

```
function limbo(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    console.log(getName(i));
  }
}
function lust(){
  limbo();
}
function gluttony(){
  lust();
}

gluttony();
```

**Result:**
*Chrome:*
[image]

*Fitefox:*
[image]

This solution was creating only *just for fun*! Don't use it for real projects. It does not depend on ES specification, it depends only on browser realization. After the next chrome/firefox/safari update it may be broken.
More than that there is no error (ha) processing - if `d` will be more than stack length - you will get an error;
For other browsers error's message pattern - you will get an error;
It must work for ES6 classes (`.split('.').pop()`), but you sill can get an error;

Comment: It is similar to It is similar to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435450/get-current-function-name-in-strict-mode/38435618#38435618

Comment: That is some intense choice of function name :p

Answer (score 23):

Any `constructor` exposes a property `name`, which is the function name. You access the `constructor` via an instance (using `new`) or a `prototype`:

```
function Person() {
  console.log(this.constructor.name); //Person
}

var p = new Person();
console.log(p.constructor.name); //Person

console.log(Person.prototype.constructor.name);  //Person
```

Comment: The first `console.log` call logs `window` or `Object` for me depending where I run it, not `Person`.

Comment: Are you sure you instantiated using "new"? Otherwise it cannot work.

Answer (score 18):

This might work for you:

```
function foo() { bar(); }

function bar() { console.log(bar.caller.name); }
```

running foo() will output "foo" or undefined if you call from an anonymous function.

It works with constructors too, in which case it would output the name of the calling constructor (eg "Foo").

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Caller

They claim it's non-standard, but also that it's supported by all major browsers: Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera and IE.

Comment: Not available in strict mode...mmm

Answer (score 11):

You could use this, for browsers that support Error.stack (not nearly all, probably)

```
function WriteSomeShitOut(){ 
  var a = new Error().stack.match(/at (.*?) /);
  console.log(a[1]);
} 
WriteSomeShitOut();
```

of course this is for the current function, but you get the idea.

happy drooling while you code

Comment: plus one for the funny function name :D

Comment: It is similar to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435450/get-current-function-name-in-strict-mode/38435618#38435618

Answer (score 10):

You can't. Functions don't have names according to the standard (though mozilla has such an attribute) - they can only be assigned to variables with names.

Also your comment:

```
// access fully qualified name (ie "my.namespace.myFunc")
```

is inside the function my.namespace.myFunc.getFn

What you can do is return the constructor of an object created by new

So you could say

```
var obj = new my.namespace.myFunc();
console.info(obj.constructor); //my.namespace.myFunc
```

Comment: i need it inside the func because i'm passing it up the inheritance chain and I omitted that stuff for brevity.

Comment: 'this' will be the instance that invoked the function. So if you  'this' inside the parent function that will give you the instance of the function that called it. That's all you should need - not sure why you need the name too

Comment: well, in the parent, i can then access other functions by convention, such as ns[child][schema] or ns[child][dbService]. Without it, I have to hard code these references in every child class.

Comment: my use case for finding the name is to make it easier for constructing console.error messages that tell where the message came from without having to revert to the stack dump. e.g. console.error({'error':{self.name reference} + " error with input parameter").
It becomes much easier to cut/paste error messages that repeat in multiple functions if you don't have to stop and change text within them each time. In my case, I'm returning promise errors from multiple promise calls - nice to know what promise/function generated the error.

Answer (score 8):

**You could use `Function.name`**:

In most implementations of JavaScript, once you have your constructor's reference in scope, you can get its string name from its name property (e.g. Function.name, or Object.constructor.name

**You could use `Function.callee`**:

The native `arguments.caller` method has been deprecated, but most browsers support `Function.caller`, which will return the actual invoking object (its body of code):
**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fcaller**

**You could create a source map**:

If what you need is the literal function signature (the "name" of it) and not the object itself, you might have to resort to something a little more customized, like creating an array reference of the API string values you'll need to access frequently. You can map them together using `Object.keys()` and your array of strings

Answer (score 7):

You can use `name` property to get the function name, unless you're using an anonymous function

For example:

```
var Person = function Person () {
  this.someMethod = function () {};
};

Person.prototype.getSomeMethodName = function () {
  return this.someMethod.name;
};

var p = new Person();
// will return "", because someMethod is assigned with anonymous function
console.log(p.getSomeMethodName());
```

now let's try with named function

```
var Person = function Person () {
  this.someMethod = function someMethod() {};
};
```

now you can use

```
// will return "someMethod"
p.getSomeMethodName()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use constructor name like:

```
{your_function}.prototype.constructor.name
```

this code simply return name of a method.

Answer (score 5):

as part as ECMAScript 6 you can use [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) method

```
function doSomething() {}

alert(doSomething.name); // alerts "doSomething"
```

Comment: In ReactJS you need to add this: console.log(this.doSomething.name);

Comment: that is outside the function

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a old question but lately I've been facing some similar issue while trying to decorate some React Component's methods, for debugging purposes. As people already said, `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee` are forbidden in strict mode which is probably enabled by default in your React transpiling. You can either disable it, or I've been able to come up with another hack, because in React all class functions are named, you can actually do this:

```
Component.prototype.componentWillMount = function componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Callee name: ', this.__proto__.constructor.toString().substr(0,30));
...
}
```

Comment: Note that Object.prototype.__proto__ is Deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Answer (score 3):

This will work in ES5, ES6, all browsers and strict mode functions.

Here's how it looks with a named function.

```
(function myName() {
  console.log(new Error().stack.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g)[1].trim());
})();
```

```
at myName (<anonymous>:2:15)
```

Here's how it looks with an anonymous function.

```
(() => {
  console.log(new Error().stack.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g)[1].trim());
})();
```

```
at <anonymous>:2:15
```

Comment: This produces different results per browser. Chrome: `at myName (<anonymous>:2:15)` Firefox: `@debugger eval code:3:3`

Comment: (function myName() {
  console.log(new Error().stack.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g)[1].trim().split(" ")[1]);
})();

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435450/get-current-function-name-in-strict-mode/38435618#38435618

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution to dynamically retrieve function names [like magic variables] is the use of scoped variables.

```
{
  function parent() {
    console.log(a.name);
  }; let a = parent
}
{
  function child() {
    console.log(a.name)
  }; let a = child
};

parent();//logs parent
child();//logs child
```

Note: Nested functions cease to be source elements, and are hence not hoisted.
Also, this technique cannot work with anonymous functions.

Comment: `let a = go`? what is `go`?

Comment: My bad,  that's meant to be "parent"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it as follows:

```
Function.prototype.myname = function() {
   return this.toString()
       .substr( 0, this.toString().indexOf( "(" ) )
       .replace( "function ", "" ); 
}
```

This code implements, in a more comfortable fashion, one response I already read here at the top of this discussion.
Now I have a member function retrieving the name of any function object.
Here's the full script ...

```
<script language="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript">

    Function.prototype.myname = function() { 
        return this.toString()
            .substr( 0, this.toString().indexOf( "(" ) )
            .replace("function ", "" ); 
    }
    function call_this( _fn ) { document.write( _fn.myname() ); }
    function _yeaaahhh() { /* do something */ }
    call_this( _yeaaahhh ); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
function AbstractDomainClass() {
    this.className = function() {
        if (!this.$className) {
            var className = this.constructor.toString();
            className = className.substr('function '.length);
            className = className.substr(0, className.indexOf('('));
            this.$className = className;
        }
        return this.$className;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
var obj = new AbstractDomainClass();
expect(obj.className()).toBe('AbstractDomainClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you wanted to do, this is what I do inside a function constructor.

```
if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
    throw "ReferenceError: " + arguments.callee.name + " is not defined";
}
```

Comment: Note: Deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Answer (score 0):

Just try `Function.name`

```
const func1 = function() {};

const object = {
  func2: function() {}
};

console.log(func1.name);
// expected output: "func1"

console.log(object.func2.name);
// expected output: "func2"
```

Comment: The question was : "How to get the function name from within that function?"
In this answer function name is known and it checked from outside of function.

Answer (score -2):

look here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1209619

```
arguments.callee.toString();
```

seems to be right for your needs.

Comment: arguments.callee.toString() just returns the source of the function.

Comment: Not allowed: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Answer (score -2):

Easy way to get function name from within fuction you are running.

```js
function x(){alert(this.name)};x()
```

Comment: gives me a GUID

Comment: be aware to the content of `this` it basically can be anything. try `(function(){console.log(this.name);}).bind({name: "put basically anything here even an object maybe a 1TB string maybe a class definition"})()`

Answer (score -2):

you can use Error.stack to trace the function name and exact position of where you are in it.

See [stacktrace.js](https://www.stacktracejs.com/)