# Navigating site (including forms) with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to automate an application that uses form security in order to upload a file and then scrape data from the returned HTML.

I started out using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246438/how-to-submit-a-form-using-phantomjs).  I can define my steps and get through the entire workflow as long as the last step is rendering the page.

Here are the two steps that are the meat of my script:

```
function() {
    page.open("https://remotesite.com/do/something", function(status) {
        if ('success' === status) {
            page.uploadFile('input[name=file]', 'x.csv');
            page.evaluate(function() {
                // assignButton is used to associate modules with an account
                document.getElementById("assignButton").click();                    
            });
        }
    });
},
function() {
    page.render('upload-results.png');
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var results = document.getElementById("moduleProcessingReport");
        console.log("results: " + results);
    });
},
```

When I run the script, I see that the output render is correct.  However, the evaluate part isn't working.  I can confirm that my DOM selection is correct by running it in the Javascript console while on the remote site.

I have seen other questions, but they revolve around using setTimeout.  Unfortunately, the step strategy from the original approach already has a timeout.

**UPDATE**
I tried a slightly different approach, using [this post](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/534-how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-phantomjs-and-jquery) and got similar results.  I believe that document uses an older PhantomJS API, so I used the 'onLoadFinished' event to drive between steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i recomend you use [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/)  or if you use PJS's webPage.injectScript() you could load up jquery and then your own script to do form input/navigation.

Comment: phantomjs also lets you inject jquery but yeah casperjs is easier

Comment: JasonS can you please share any such article, it will help everybody

Comment: This is specific to my SaaS, but look on this page's "Page Automation" section for details: https://phantomjscloud.com/docs/