# Phantomjs not creating screenshot

Tags: php, screenshot, phantomjs

I was try to create a web screenshot with phantomjs,But alwaise it result a blank image.I am using Fedora OS.Here is my javascript.

**screen.js**

```
        var WebPage = require('webpage');
        page = WebPage.create();
        page.open('http://google.com');
        page.onLoadFinished = function() {
        page.render('googleScreenShot' + '.png');
        phantom.exit();}
```

And here is my php code

**shot.php**

```
     $exec = '/var/www/html/test/bin/phantomjs  /var/www/html/test/screen.js'; 
     $escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($exec);
     exec($escaped_command);
```

But the created image was blank.phantomjs have executre permission.Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but this may work,try it

```
    var WebPage = require('webpage');
    page = WebPage.create();
    page.open('http://google.com');
    page.onLoadFinished = function() {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('googleScreenShot' + '.png');
            phantom.exit();
          }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: yes but javascript working asycn. because of this it is unknown when work the render process so it can be work on windows.you have 2 choices first one is explained by @victory, the other choice is waitfor() method as exampled at this link  : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem because the time your code execute the next line of code is more faster than phantomjs logging that `page.onLoadStarted` is True.

easy and clean way to fix this is by adding a time interval of 100 ms between each function and make all your code in functions, check Vijay Boyapati method for more clarification : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256079/1738230

Answer (score 0):

In dealing with this problem I completed a code module, as follows:

[link](https://github.com/PyCN/Anti-Anti-Spider/blob/master/phantomjs/get_page_printscreen/rasterize.js)

You can download it locally, and then invoke it by command

```
phantomjs rasterize.js "http://www.google.com" 800px*800px > wait.html
```