# Fetch an HTML form, parse it, and submit it automatically in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, node.js

I need to write a program that checks a URL: if there is a form, it needs to fill in all text boxes with a specific string, and submit it.

I have already written the function that loads the form using `http.request`. At this point, I need to analyse what comes in, and submit it.

What's the best way to do it? I could:

- Place the response in a DOM representation and parse it that way with https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom
- Use a headless browser like https://github.com/assaf/zombie to handle things. Note that the number of open and un-responded issues in the project worries me

Am I missing something? Maybe a much better way to go about this?

Comment: You might want to look at [PhanotmJS](http://phantomjs.org/) as well.

Comment: @PeterVC yes, that's better PhanotmJS. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9256079/1154165