# auto submit form using cron job

Tags: php, cron

My requirement: 
I need to get data from database and submit the values on some other website form after each 2 min .

I am planning to do this by creating as similar form and populating values from db
then submit it using `document.getElementById("webform-form").submit();`

It works fine if I manually run the url

but it doesn't work when I submit it using cron job.

Cronjob is ignoring this state of form submission. I want to know whether it is possible
to do it using cronjob and form submission. If not, please suggest me how should I proceed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show the code of the cronjob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method you've described you need your page to be loaded by real browser and to be run by javascript in it.

I think you want to do a POST request directly from your PHP script without being loaded by browser. It can be done by [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You can find [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) on this site.

Comment: We should keep in mind that you can't submit a form with CURL if you have CSRF in place :)

Comment: well, actually you can, but you need to download the page with the form and parse it first:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "headless" browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) to submit the form and then put the PhantomJS script on a cron - which shouldn't be that hard.

You can find a sample form submit for Phantom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256079/81937) and then you could just put it in the cron like this:

```
*/2 * * * * phantomjs you-form-submit-script.js
```