# How to change current page in Phantomjs using buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, phantomjs

I have start to using Phantomjs and I don't understand something. How to change current page using buttons? For example I've got a code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://ru-ru.facebook.com', function() {
    page.injectJs('jQuery.js');
        page.evaluate(function() {
        $('#email').val('MyLogin');
        $('#pass').val('MyPass');
        $('#u_0_l').click();
        });
    page.render('example.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

So after clicking a button I need to go to the next page. How can I do this?

Comment: did you refer to docs http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/

Comment: maybe this post can help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246438/how-to-submit-a-form-using-phantomjs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `$.click()` actually worked, you need to wait until the page has loaded.

**setTimeout:**

You may feel lucky and try it with

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    // form vals and click
});
setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('example.png');
    phantom.exit();
}, 3000); // 3 sec timeout
```

**waitFor selector:**

You may use the [waitFor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) example from the phantomjs package to wait for an element that you know is only on the loaded page, but not on the current page.

**waitFor loadFinished:**

You may combine [waitFor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) with the [onLoadFinished](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html) callback handler to do wait for the next page to load. This is preferable since this would work every time and would not impose overshooting with a conservative timeout.

**Just use [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/):**

Nothing more to add.