# Tricky "password" field in WordPress install script using CodeCeption

Tags: php, wordpress, codeception

I'm trying to use WordPress CodeCeption to run a script to install WordPress. I'm using PHPBrowser which is a headless browser.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Setup WordPress');
$I->amOnPage("/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1");
$I->see("Below you should enter your database connection details.");
$I->fillField('dbname', 'wordpress_unit_test');
$I->fillField('uname', 'wordpressuser');
$I->click('.button');
$I->click('.button');
$I->fillField('weblog_title', 'AWS Remote Dev Server');
$I->fillField('user_name', 'admin');
$I->fillField('#pass1-text', 'password');
$I->fillField('admin_email', 'admin@email.com');
$I->click('.button');
```

It's getting hung up on the password field in the WP install screen. Any idea how to fill this field? I've tried:

```
$I->fillField('pass1-text', 'password');
$I->fillField('#pass1-text', 'password');
```

But I keep getting:

```
 Test  tests/runner/SetupWordPressCept.php
 Step  Fill field "#pass1-text","password"
 Fail  Form field by Label or CSS element with '#pass1-text' was not found.
```

[image]

Comment: Does WP use JS on this input field? Anybody know? PHPBrowser doesn't run JS.

Comment: '#pass1-text' makes me think you are targeting an ID, maybe this will work: 
$I->fillField(['id' => 'pass1-text'],  'password');

Comment: sunomad that didn't work. :( It starts out prefilled. I think it's JS somehow.

Comment: strange, are you sure the ID is correct? 
If you really think it's JS, you can try running the tests with Selenium

Comment: It works fine in Selenium, so it's an issue between PHPBrowser and the specific password field in the WP install. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

PHPBrowser does not support JavaScript, so if you want to check how this page looks for PHPBrowser, you should disable scripts in your browser (for example with [NoScript](https://noscript.net/)).

In this case `pass1` is a ID and `admin_password` is a name:

```
$I->fillField('admin_password', 'password');
```