# Intercept Ajax Response with Python + Selenium + PhantomJS

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I need to extract email address off a web page. The webpage contains a link to email address. I click on the link. It sends an XHR request. The ajax response is captured by a js script that parses the response and opens a mail client.

As the Ajax response doesn't change the html in any way, I can't extract the email by monitoring the html.

I need to capture the Ajax response myself so that I can parse it and save it in a database.

```
#
# Initialize browser etc.
#
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
emailLink = driver.find_element_by_class_name('email_add')
emailLink.click()

#There is no change in html. I can't find the email address
```

By using Firefox webdriver in place of PhantomJS, I ensured that the code is working fine. Firefox opens a mail client in response to ajax reply.

I tried issuing the request using requests and urllib2, but somehow the webserver identifies these manually generated requests and redirects to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I took the intercept code from [here](https://gist.github.com/suprememoocow/2823600) and wrapped it in a PhantomJS script which injected it into the page I was scraping. Note that the page has to be loaded before injecting the XHTTP intercept.
Also, had to tell PhantomJS to intercept and print out messages printed to console.log.

I used the [functions] technique from Vijay's accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246438/how-to-submit-a-form-using-phantomjs)

<sub>For a more interesting live data feed try using http://flightaware.com/live/ instead of maps.google.com below, but be patient, it may take a minute or five to get an update.</sub>

Here's the <strike>partial (untested other than parse, sorry)</strike> PhantomJS script:

```
  var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;

  page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("load started");
  };

  page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log("load finished");
  };

  page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  };

  var steps = [
  function() {
    //Load Login Page
    page.open("http://maps.google.com");
  },    
  function() {

    page.render('check.png');  // see what's happened.
    page.evaluate(
     function( x) {
    //inject following code from https://gist.github.com/suprememoocow/2823600
    // I've added console.log() calls along with onConsoleMessage above to see XHR responses.
    (function(XHR) {
        "use strict";

        var stats = [];
        var timeoutId = null;

        var open = XHR.prototype.open;
        var send = XHR.prototype.send;

        XHR.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
            this._url = url;
            open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
        };

        XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
            var self = this;
            var start;
            var oldOnReadyStateChange;
            var url = this._url;

            function onReadyStateChange() {
                if(self.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                    var time = new Date() - start;                
                    stats.push({
                        url: url,
                        duration: time                    
                    });

                   console.log( "Request:" + data);
                   console.log( "Response:" + this.responseText );

                    if(!timeoutId) {
                        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                            var xhr = new XHR();
                            xhr.noIntercept = true;
                            xhr.open("POST", "/clientAjaxStats", true);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
                            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ stats: stats } ));                        

                            timeoutId = null;
                            stats = []; 
                        }, 2000);
                    }                
                }

                if(oldOnReadyStateChange) {
                    oldOnReadyStateChange();
                }
            }

            if(!this.noIntercept) {
                start = new Date();

                if(this.addEventListener) {
                    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", onReadyStateChange, false);
                } else {
                    oldOnReadyStateChange = this.onreadystatechange; 
                    this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChange;
                }
            }

            send.call(this, data);
        }
    })(XMLHttpRequest);


     },""
    );
    }, 
    function() {
        // try something else here.  Add more steps as necessary
    }
];

interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
     // commented out to run until ctrl-c
    //console.log("test complete!");
    //phantom.exit();
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

> I tried issuing the request using requests and urllib2, but somehow
>   the webserver identifies these manually generated requests and
>   redirects to the home page.

If this is the problem then make the server think that the request is coming from a browser. change the user agent

[Changing user agent on urllib2.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen)