# Automating browser from terminal

Tags: linux, windows, server

Is there a way to automate a server so that it can open browser at a specific time and input a given email in a form then submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It can be done by using headless browsers as suggested by @TNU, I have done it using [Phantom Js](http://phantomjs.org/), Now there are many ways you can do this.

Just write a javascript in a file and schedule the job using cron from terminal.

Or you can use [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) another library written on top of phantom Js.

Or you can use [Ghost driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) for connecting to phantom headless browser to execute and schedule the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could use headless browsers, which don't have user interfaces and can be controlled programmatically. Check this list for a list of [Headless Browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers)

Comment: What about filling a form?

Comment: You can use the browser's api to interact with DOM elements. Check this for [an exmaple using PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256079/4585994)