# How to name an arrow function to make the name available in Chrome CPU profiler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, arrow-functions

This is a variation of [How do I write a named arrow function in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015) question, though the specific aim is to name the function object in a way that would make it available for Chrome CPU profiler.

I have tried the following:

```js
let unnamed;

unnamed = () => {

};

Object.defineProperty(unnamed, 'name', {
    value: 'XXX'
});

Object.defineProperty(unnamed.constructor, 'name', {
    value: 'YYY'
});

Object.defineProperty(unnamed, 'displayName', {
    value: 'ZZZ'
});

console.log('unnamed.name', unnamed.name);
console.log('unnamed.constructor.name', unnamed.constructor.name);
console.log('unnamed.displayName', unnamed.displayName);

export default unnamed;
```

However, whatever I do, CPU profiler is showing it as `(anonymous function)`.

Interestingly, if you throw an error, the stack trace uses `displayName` property.

[image: Error stack]

Comment: Found a relevant thread on Chromium issue tracker, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=17356

Answer (score 1):

CPU profiler doesn't use displayName or Function.name. There is another issue for this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=559532

For stack trace function name resolution algo use first defined property from list: displayName, Function.name, V8 function inferred name.