# Why is `mapStateToProps` always an anonymous function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In the [official documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) for using React with Redux, the documentation seems to always define `mapStateToProps` as an anonymous arrow function assigned to a variable:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}
```

This also seems to be the usage pattern for `mapDispatchToProps` and other functions passed to `connect` both in the docs and in the community.

It seems it would be much more simple, and follow traditional usage, to define it like so:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}
```

Why is this done? Is there a practical reason for this, or is it just preference? Is it frowned upon to use a standard function definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No particular reason, it's just the style that was used in writing the docs.  Feel free to write your `mapState` function as either arrows or standard function declarations, declared standalone or declared inline.  No difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really anonymous though?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}
console.log(mapStateToProps.name)
```

More info:

[How do I write a named arrow function in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015)

For all intends and purpose, that `mapStateToProps` is going to show the right name in stack traces, as opposed to `<anonymous function>`.

Comment: The technical term is still anonymous functions I believe, even though engines have added better handling for them. You're right though, it will show up in a stack trace for most newer browsers (as will old-style anonymous functions).

Comment: Named fat arrow expression are in fact fully covered by the spec
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Off course it's true that it's only supported by newer browsers.

Comment: Yes, but those are still called anonymous function definitions, not named functions. They just have `name` parameters on the variable. The spec you linked to uses that terminology, and the [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) also does.

Comment: @ChrisFoster
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-isanonymousfunctiondefinition

Comment: You're not reading the specs you are linking to. `IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition` is called during [lefthand assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), and **always** returns true because [`HasName` is **always** false for arrow functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-hasname). Then, seeing that it is an anonymous function, lefthand assignment adds a `name` parameter to the lefthand expression (the variable). _The function is anonymous!_