# Anonymous function expression in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, anonymous-function, function-expression

I am using Google Chrome version 52 64-bit.
I found out that if I use anonymous function expression ex.

```
//  Anonymous function expression 
var expressionFunc = function(){
    return true;
};
```

The variable `expressionFunc` will hold the assigned anonymous function,
But it is also adding a name property `expressionFunc` to this function. 
So if I do  `expressionFunc.name` in the console, 
It will give me `expressionFunc`.

From what I know this anonymous function expression should stay anonymous, 
And the function referenced by the variable should not contain the variable name in the name property of the function.

Why is chrome assigning name property to an anonymous function?

Comment: It's my understanding that you're not creating an anonymous function here, you're just declaring the function with different syntax. Happy for someone who knows the standard a bit more to elaborate. An anonymous function would be more like (function () { alert(true); })();

Comment: The behaviour in Firefox is different, suggesting that it's not clear-cut.

Comment: This is called inline anonymous function expression. this function do not have a name so it is anonymous inline function and the assignment to the variable makes it  an  inline anonymous function expression

Comment: Sorry forgot to add: `(function () { alert(true); })();` Your function is called self invoking anonymous function.

Comment: This code: `var expressionFunc = function somename(){}; console.log expressionFunc.name;` shows `somename` in all browsers. Only Chrome gives a name to the anonymous function in the original question. (Browsers tried: Edge, Firefox, Opera, Chrome)

Comment: Yes, it's part of the not-so-new-any-more ES6 standard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/1048572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Says this

> Browsers that implement ES6 functions can infer the name of an
>   anonymous function from its syntactic position. For example:

```
var f = function() {};
console.log(f.name); // "f"
```

There's no particular explanation on that page.

This page

http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html

Says this

> With regard to names, arrow functions are like anonymous function
>   expressions:

```
     const func = () => {};
     console.log(func.name); // func
```

> From now on, whenever you see an anonymous function expression, you
>   can assume that an arrow function works the same way.

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/1048572 (referenced by @bergi) is pretty comprehensive, and points to the source in the specification.

Comment: Notice that browsers did this inference since long for stack traces, it's only since ES6 that they make it available as a property and that there are set rules for when to do it.