# Es6 Arrow function to normal js

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have been trying to understand es6 arrow function. I read some articles introducing it. But I'am still not getting it fully.

For example I have this code:

```
sortedArticles(): Article[] {
    return this.articles.sort((a: Article, b: Article) => b.votes -  a.votes);
}
```

It sorts the below array:

```
[
  new Article('Angular 2', 'http://angular.io', 3),
  new Article('Fullstack', 'http://fullstack.io', 2),
  new Article('Angular Homepage', 'http://angular.io', 1),
];
```

How would the same code look in plain old js? I am not able to fully get it.

Comment: In general ES5: `function(a, b) { return a + b}` translates to ES6 `(a, b) => a + b;`. So to fast transform between the two 1. remove `function` but preserve the brackets with parameters (aside from if you have a single parameter - you can omit the brackets, then). 2. remove the `return` keyword, if the function is on one line. Keep it otherwise. 3. Remove the `{` and `} brackets if on one line. Keep them otherwise. 4. Done. That's a good rule of thumb to follow most of the time, unless you want to use `this`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would look like this if you just converted the arrow function to a `function` function:

```
sortedArticles(): Article[] {
    return this.articles.sort(function(a: Article, b: Article) { return b.votes -  a.votes;});
// ---------------------------^^^^^^^^------------------------^^^-------------------------^^
}
```

...but note that there's more going on there than ES2015 ("ES6"). The `: Article[]` part is saying that `sortedArticles` returns an array of `Article`. (And similarly the `: Article` qualifiers on `a` and `b`.) That's not JavaScript at all. It looks like [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org).

The pure JavaScript version would just drop those type annotations:

```
sortedArticles() {
    return this.articles.sort(function(a, b) { return b.votes -  a.votes;});
}
```

But TypeScript's "fat arrow" functions work largely the same way ES2015's arrow functions do, so let's continue on the basis that we're talking about ES2015 arrow functions:

There are four fundamental differences<sup>1</sup> between arrow functions and `function` functions:

1. They close over `this`, `super`, and several other things,<sup>2</sup> they don't have their own versions of those like `function` functions do. (A consequence of this is that they can use `super` if they're defined in a context that can use `super`, which `function` functions cannot.)
2. They can have a *concise* body rather than a verbose one (but they can have a verbose body as well).
3. They cannot be used as constructors. E.g., you can't use `new` with an arrow function. A consequence of this is that arrow functions don't have a `prototype` property on them (since it's only used if the function is used with `new`).
4. There is no *generator* syntax for arrow functions. E.g., there is no arrow equivalent to `function *foo() { ... }`.

These three functions are all effectively the same, since they don't use `this` or `arguments`:

```
// A `function` function
var f1 = function(x) {
    return x * 2;
};

// An arrow function with a verbose body
var f2 = x => {
    return x * 2;
};

// An arrow function with a concise body
var f3 = x => x * 2;
```

(If they used `this` or `arguments`, they would **not** be the same.)

Note that the concise body doesn't have a `{` after the `=>` and must contain a single top-level expression (which can of course have subexpressions), which is used as the return value.

---

<sup>1</sup> You'll find people telling you there's a fifth: That arrow functions cannot have a name. [That's a myth.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/157247) Arrow functions can have names; the arrow functions above have true names, `f2` and `f3` respectively. It's not just the variables that have names, the functions do as well.

<sup>2</sup> Specifically, [they close over](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) `this`, `super`, `arguments` (the automatic pseudo-array of runtime arguments), and `new.target`.

---

*A huge thank you to [CodingIntrigue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571194/codingintrigue) for pointing out several errors and omissions in the earlier versions of this answer.*

Comment: Yes, it's typescript. The code is from Angular2 project am tinkering with. Your explanation really broke it down to me. I hope this helps others who are facing similar confusions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with arrow function, or if it's complicated, you can use `JS Refactor`, it's a Visual Studio Code extension. It can convert arrow function to normal function. Hope it helps someone.