# Turning an arrow function to a regular function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

i have to turn an arrow function to a regular one. The problem is that the arrow function is pretty different from those i'm used to work with hence harder to transform. I need your help please. Here is the arrow function followed by the regular function i tried to code.
The functions :

```
(name) => {
    `Bonjour, ${name} ! Comment vas-tu ?`;
}
taille = () => 
{

function(name)
{
return `Bonjour, ${name} ! Comment vas-tu?`;
}
```

Comment: Whats the `taille = () => 
{` part?

Comment: why you want to do that ? an arrow function is fine it's also a function, and also you have a return in one and not the other

Comment: It looks like your arrow function does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Lk77 It's presumably an exercise to understand the different syntaxes.

Comment: i think you are confused by the {} part, you need a return if you use {}, you can omit the return when doing `(e) => e.length` for example but not with {}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ECMAScript 6's arrow function to a regular function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668185/converting-ecmascript-6s-arrow-function-to-a-regular-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Es6 Arrow function to normal js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341121/es6-arrow-function-to-normal-js)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent regular function is almost identical to the arrow function.

```
function(name) {
  `Bonjour, ${name} ! Comment vas-tu?`;
}
```

When an arrow function's body is surrounded by `{}`, it's the same as the body of a regular function. The differences between these types of arrow and regular functions are related to the scope of `this` and the availability of the special variable `arguments`, but these are not relevant in your example.

Note that this function is not very useful, since the string is never returned.

An arrow function only has an implicit `return` if the body is not surrounded by `{}`. Your regular function is equivalent to this:

```
(name) => `Bonjour, ${name} ! Comment vas-tu ?`
```