# What does () => {} mean in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-browser-sync

I'm in the learning path of js, and just started using the yeoman generators. And I use gulp for the pre-processing and other stuffs. When I was going through the gulpfile.js, I found this block of code.

```
gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'html', 'watch'], () => {
    browserSync({
        notify: false,
        port: 9000,
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        }
    })
});
```

I can understand that when we execute `gulp-serve`, it runs styles, html and watch task and opens a development server in the port 9000.

But I don't understand what does this `() =>` means.

Will be very grateful if someone can tell me what does that mean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's an es6 arrow function

Comment: its an anonymous function, () => {} can act as an substitute for function(){}

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds: [The aren't always anonymous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/157247).

Comment: my mistake, I always used them as an anonymous function so I mistook them as anonymous functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called `Arrow functions`

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

In simple words, its a substitute for `function(){}` except for `this` context

This is how your code would look:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'html', 'watch'], function() {
    browserSync({
        notify: false,
        port: 9000,
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        }
    })
});
```

(An anonymous function passed in as third argument)

It's an **ES6 Feature** anyways, you can explore more features like this in [this](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) link :P

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That made things clear :)

Comment: Nice to know :) Feel free to accept it

Answer (score 1):

It is defining an inline function that takes no params. The body of the function is in the {}. This new function is then passed as a callback to the task() function.

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 Arrow function

Its an anonymous function. The code you have could be

`gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'html', 'watch'], function () {
    browserSync({
        notify: false,
        port: 9000,
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        }
    })
});`

The awesome thing about arrow functions is that you can still use `this` in context. you dont have to define something like `let self = this;` outside of the function.