# function to es6 class base style

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, ecmascript-6, eventemitter

i'm newie in es6 and eventEmitter both. i've prepare a module in node event base style and now i'm trying to transform as es6 calass style. here it is

// **eventStyle.js**

```
const events = require('events');
const util = require('util');

var Customer = function() {
  // console.log(typeof this);
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  //    this is only public function
  this.register = function(email, password) {
  var newCustomer = {email:email, password:password}
  this.emit("newRegistation", newCustomer)
  }

  var _validate = function(customer) {
  if(customer.password=='password')
  this.emit("validated", customer)
  else
  this.emit("registationFailed", customer)
  }

  var _insert = function(customer) {
  this.emit("added", customer)
  }

  var _sendEmail = function(customer) {
  this.emit("emailSent", customer)
  }

  var _registationSuccessful = function(customer) {
  this.emit("registationSuccessful", customer)
  }

  this.on("newRegistation", _validate)
  this.on("validated", _insert)
  this.on("added", _sendEmail)
  this.on("emailSent", _registationSuccessful)
}

util.inherits(Customer, events.EventEmitter )
```

module.exports =  Customer

//**eventApp.js**

```
const Customer = require('./eventStyle');
customer = new Customer();
// console.log(customer);
customer.on("registationSuccessful", ()=>{
  console.log("well done");
})

customer.on("registationFailed", ()=>{
  console.log("sorry error");
})
console.log(typeof customer.register);
setTimeout(()=>customer.register(), 1000);
```

//now my es6 based code (not working for me ) of **eventStyle.js**

```
const events = require('events');
const util = require('util');

class Customer {
  constuctor(){
  console.log("cons",this);
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.on("newRegistation", _validate)
  this.on("validated", _insert)
  this.on("added", _sendEmail)
  this.on("emailSent", _registationSuccessful)
  }

  //    this is only public function
  register(email, password) {
  var newCustomer = {email:email, password:password}
  console.log(this);
  this.emit("newRegistation", newCustomer)
  }

  _validate(customer) {
  if(customer.password=='password')
  this.emit("validated", customer)
  else
  this.emit("registationFailed", customer)
  }

  _insert(customer) {
  this.emit("added", customer)
  }

  _sendEmail(customer) {
  this.emit("emailSent", customer)
  }

  _registationSuccessful(customer) {
  this.emit("registationSuccessful", customer)
  }
}
util.inherits(Customer, events.EventEmitter )

module.exports =  Customer
```

somebody tell what i'm mistaking. thanks in advance

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: Maybe Babel is what you need.

Comment: @Sunday: Sort of the other way around.

Comment: Never change a running system... Why do you need classes? Does it not work fine without?

Comment: *"now my es6 based code (not working for me )"* Not working ***how***? What issues are you having? What happens? What do you expect to happen instead? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: sorry accidentally question posted before complete and i face trouble with markdown when edit it. now it's complete

Comment: runnning eventApp.js it should console "well done" or "sorry error" but not console in es6 style

Comment: thanks @TJ.  but i still not found my mistake

Answer (score 2):

<s>Five</s> Four main issues:

1. You've missed out the first 'r' in `constructor`
2. You need to use `this` when referring to object methods
3. <s>You need to preserve `this` in callbacks (see [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)).</s> In this **specific** case, you don't; `EventEmitter`'s `on` calls them with `this` set correctly ([reference](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners)). If that guarantee weren't provided, you would.
4. You need `extends events` on the `class` line (the more normal thing to do would be to call the import `EventEmitter` and then use `extends EventEmitter`).
5. You don't use this style to call the super constructor with `class` `events.EventEmitter.call(this);`. Instead, you call `super`. You must do so before any use of `this`.

So the minimal changes version is

```
class Customer extends events {
```

and in the `constructor`:

```
constructor() { // Added missing 'r' in "constructor"
    super();    // Added
    console.log("cons", this);
    // Removed `events.EventEmitter.call(this);` here
    // On all four of the following, note `this.`
    this.on("newRegistation", this._validate);
    this.on("validated", this._insert);
    this.on("added", this._sendEmail);
    this.on("emailSent", this._registationSuccessful);
}
```

**But**, if you don't want the `_` methods to be public, there's no need for them to be public; just create them in the constructor:

```
class Customer {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("cons", this);

        const _validate = customer => {
            if (customer.password == 'password')
                this.emit("validated", customer);
            else
                this.emit("registationFailed", customer);
        };

        const _insert = customer => {
            this.emit("added", customer);
        };

        const _sendEmail = customer => {
            this.emit("emailSent", customer);
        };

        const _registationSuccessful = customer => {
            this.emit("registationSuccessful", customer);
        };

        this.on("newRegistation", _validate);
        this.on("validated", _insert);
        this.on("added", _sendEmail);
        this.on("emailSent", _registationSuccessful);
    }

    //    this is only public function
    register(email, password) {
        var newCustomer = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }
        console.log(this);
        this.emit("newRegistation", newCustomer)
    }
}
```

That second form does create separate function objects for each instance, but the overhead of that is quite small. You'd need millions of instances of your class for it to matter.

You don't have to create them separately, you could do:

```
this.on("newRegistration", customer => {
    if (customer.password == 'password')
        this.emit("validated", customer);
    else
        this.emit("registationFailed", customer);
});
```

...and so on. But if you did, the function would be anonymous, which is less helpful in stack traces and such if something goes wrong. (Whereas the ones in `const _validate = ...` form [have names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015/37488652#37488652).)

---

About calling `super`: If you want to pass along constructor parameters, you can do that by using rest notation:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost done, missing only extends to event emitter and call to super in constructor to initialise super class (if you don't, `this` doesn't exist) :

```
const events = require('events');
const util = require('util');

class Customer extends events {
  constructor(){
  super();
  console.log("cons",this);
  this.on("newRegistation", this._validate)
  this.on("validated", this._insert)
  this.on("added", this._sendEmail)
  this.on("emailSent", this._registationSuccessful)
  }

  //    this is only public function
  register(email, password) {
  var newCustomer = {email:email, password:password}
  console.log(this);
  this.emit("newRegistation", newCustomer)
  }

  _validate(customer) {
  if(customer.password=='password')
  this.emit("validated", customer)
  else
  this.emit("registationFailed", customer)
  }

  _insert(customer) {
  this.emit("added", customer)
  }

  _sendEmail(customer) {
  this.emit("emailSent", customer)
  }

  _registationSuccessful(customer) {
  this.emit("registationSuccessful", customer)
  }
}

module.exports =  Customer
```

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

Comment: Fixed, typo mistake : `constuctor` => `constructor`

Comment: I don't agree, only the class which extends events is going to call emit, so this is the caller Customer and always the caller Customer. I just do the test, and `this` still my instanciated object, no need of bind

Comment: @Fefux: (If you don't `@` notify, I don't receive notification of the comment.) In this **specific** case, you're quite right; [`EventEmitter` guarantees](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners) that `this` will be set to the instance by `on`.

Comment: thanks @Fefux . you correct TJ & me, really appreciable