# How can I debug anonymous JavaScript functions in Chrome's performance analyzer?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working with Angular 4 and I'm using a lot of anonymous arrow functions (`() => {}`). Is it possible to determine which of these functions I'm debugging in Chrome's performance analyzer without giving them names?

Here's an example of what I'm looking at;

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't want to create a variable containing all anonymous functions like in this post. I want to track anonymous functions, I should change the title of my post,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a named arrow function in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015)

Comment: Based on the edits/clarifications, I've retracted my dupe vote, but I suspect the answer is probably still "You can't, you need to name them", which [the post I originally linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015) shows you how to.

Comment: I think this is a totally valid question and the close votes should be removed unless there really is a duplicate of this exact same question. If anything, DevTools needs to provide a more straightforward UI for this pretty obvious use case.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the function in the **Main** chart to select it. DevTools highlights it blue. In the **Summary** tab you can see more info about that function.

[image: Summary tab]

Click the link next to **Function** in order to view that function's source code in the **Sources** panel.

[image: Sources panel]

I think the Performance panel automatically formats minified files, but if not, you can manually unminfiy by clicking [**Format**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format).