# Does this JS function param syntax (object initializer with property defaults, similar to rest/spread params) have a name and effect?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I was reading the [logging](https://github.com/dylang/logging) library source code when I found [syntax](https://github.com/dylang/logging/blob/master/src/logging.js#L55) I had never seen before, and which didn't seem to have any effect when evaluated via an interpreter:

```
const createLogger = (title,
                     {
                         debugFunction = createDebug(title),
                         logFunction = console.log
                     } = {}) => { /* ... */ }
```

1. What is this syntax called?
2. What effect does this syntax have?
3. Can the object be referenced from within the function body?

Output of `ts-node` attempt to recreate:

```
> const testFn2 = (arg1, {dFn = console.debug, lFn = console.log} = {}) => { console.log(arguments) }
undefined

> testFn2(1)
{ '0': 1 }
undefined

> testFn2(1, 2)
{ '0': 1, '1': 2 }
undefined

> testFn2(1, {})
{ '0': 1, '1': {} }
undefined
```

Comment: It is the [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of

- [Default parameter values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)
- Destructuring parameters (which works just like [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

along with

- [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) (obviously)
- Inferred function names (see: [*How do I write a named arrow function in ES2015?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015))
- An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

...all of which were added in ES2015.

It creates a constant, `createLogger`, and sets its value to a function named `createLogger`, which accepts two parameters: A title (`title`), and an object. The object is *destructured* into `debugFunction` and `logFunction` parameters, and is defaulted to `{}` if not present.

Here's a simpler example of a destructured parameter:

```js
function foo({a, b}) {
// Note -----^----^
  console.log(a, ",", b);
}

const o = {a: 1, b: 2};
foo(o); // 1 , 2
```

Note how we're calling `foo` with an object, but `foo`'s code works with two parameters whose values were *destructured* from that object's properties.

If we were to call `foo` with no argument, we'd get an error because the destructuring tries to access the properties on the parameter, and accessing properties on `undefined` fails:

```js
function foo({a, b}) {
  console.log(a, ",", b);
}

foo(); // Fails
```

If we add in a default value for the parameter, it works:

```js
function foo({a, b} = {a: "default a"}) {
// ----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  console.log(a, ",", b);
}

foo(); // default a , undefined (since there's no `b` in the default)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called argument destructuring coupled with default values:

```js
let default1 = 1;
let default2 = 2;

const func = ({a = default1, b = default2} = {}) => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}

// Here since no value is specified, the default argument will be {a: 1, b: 2}
func();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at an [object destructring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), in this case used to initialize local variables and assign them default values without having to declare them in the function body. It's a pattern to avoid writing extra code; if you didn't have the destructing syntax, you would basically write:

```
const createLogger = (name, params = {}) => {
    let debugFunction = params.debugFunction || createDebug(name);
    let logFunction = params.logFunction || console.log;

     // do stuff
}
```

At this point it may create more problems than is worth it for small amount of code it eliminates; better to be clear than concise, especially on a large project. You *could* combine multiple ternary assignments instead of writing an if-else block, but that would be terrible to read. On the other hand, this style may gain more prevalence.