# the name of function return anonymous when I define a function with new Function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to define a function with constructor Function as below, but why the name of the function return anonymous?

```
let sayHi = new Function('alert("Hello")');
//this will return anonymous
sayHi.name
```

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you are creating anonymouse function.

Named functions are initialized with:

```
function sayHi() {
  alert('Hello');
};

sayHi.name // sayHi
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the name `"anonymous"`, particularly since other anonymous functions have a blank name. The real answer here is: Because that's how the `Function` constructor is defined (as of ES2015).

Answer (score 2):

> ...but why the name of the function return anonymous?

Because that's how the `Function` constructor is defined. This is covered by the spec. The [`Function` constructor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-constructor) calls the abstract operation [CreateDynamicFunction](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-createdynamicfunction), which sets the name to `"anonymous"` near the end:

> 39. Perform SetFunctionName(*F*, "anonymous").

This is in contrast to a non-dynamic function with no name, which is relatively difficult to create these days because ES2015 defined that names are assigned to functions created with anonymous (!) function expressions in most situations.

The exception is assigning to a property on a pre-existing object:

```js
const o = {};
o.foo = function() { };
console.log(o.foo.name); // ""
```

---

Just for completeness, here are some functions that use neither `""` nor `"anonymous"` as their `name`:

```js
function foo() {
}
console.log(foo.name);

const bar = function() { };
console.log(bar.name);

const baz = () => { };
console.log(baz.name);
```

(Yes, those second two are assigned a name as **specified behavior**; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/157247) for details.)

Answer (score 0):

Function constructor does not accept a name, therefore it is always anonymous as specified in the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Answer (score -1):

Functions created with the syntax `new Function(...)` or just `Function(...)` create Function objects and their name is "anonymous".

```
(new Function).name; // "anonymous"
```

Hope this helps you!