# getting the function name of a function in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

If I have this code:

```
const foo = cb => {console.log(cb.name)} //access here

const bar = ()=>null

foo(()=>bar())
```

Is there a way for me to access `bar`'s prototype from `foo`? (in this case the name)

```
cb.name // '' (anonymous function)
cb().name // tries to access null.name (return of bar)
```

This question is more about my curiosity, I'm **not** looking for workarounds.

Comment: no, that's the point of arrow functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the name, kind of:

```
 const foo = cb => {
  console.log(cb.toString())
 };
```

But no, thats not useful at all, dont do that.

> Is there a way for me to access bar's prototype from foo?

No, no way from within the code. Add a breakpoint with the debugger, then you can navigate there via stack > cb.