# TypeScript error: JSX element type 'Tree' does not have any construct or call signatures. I'm not able to import my own component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I try to import my own component I get error:

> TS2604: JSX element type 'Tree' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Why? What is going on? How to do I provide TS a signature of my `<Tree>` component?

My code.

File one that imports:

```js
// App.tsx

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tree from './index'; // <= Import

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tree />, // <= error is thrown here
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

File two that exports:

```js
// index.js

export default (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Master>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
              <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Master>
    </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're exporting isn't a component, it's an *element* (the element resulting from creating the Provider component via `<Provider>...</Provider>`).

To make it a component, make it a function returning the structure:

```
export default function Tree() {
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Master>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
              <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Master>
    </Provider>
  );
}; // ***
```

In that example I've used a traditional function (via the `function` keyword), but it could be an arrow function if you prefer:

```
const Tree = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    ...
  </Provider>
);
export default Tree;
```

In both cases, the function will have a name (`Tree`), which is useful for debugging. (Yes, the arrow function will [really have a name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/157247). :-) )

Comment: Pretty sure "export default const Tree" is not a valid syntax, but "const Tree" followed by "export default Tree" would be ;)

Comment: @ArnaudRochez - **Doh!** Thanks. I keep forgetting about that gap in the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the Tree Component into a function like this:

```
// index.js

export default () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Master>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
              <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Master>
    </Provider>
);
```

Comment: The problem with exporting an expression like that is that the function will have the name `default` (or possibly no name at all, depending on whether a bundler is being used and if so, how it translates `export`), which isn't very useful in stack traces, etc., when debugging.

Comment: Totally agree with that, but I had the feeling that that's what he tried to achieve (since the Element he tried to export in the first place was anonymous as well)

Comment: True, but elements don't really have names anyway, and don't appear in stack traces. :-)