# Why arrow function name must be const/let?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsx

I have a tsx file with react-native. My function name is underlined if function is not set to const or let with this message:

> Cannot find name 'goBack'

```
goBack = () => {
    // do stuff
}
```

But it works if I set const or let:

```
const goBack = () => {
    // do stuff
}
```

Why ?

Comment: That depends on where it is defined in your "tsx file". Is it inside a class (thus being a property of that class), or is it outside of a class definition? The former is allowed, while the latter isnt

Comment: Somehow it seems unlikely that your question is related to [tag:tsx]...

Comment: Sure, makes sense. Do you have an ambient variable named `goBack` defined somewhere? That is what you are trying to assign a value to. If not you need a local one and you do that with either let/var/const. This is not just an arrow function, it would also have this error if you did a simple string assignment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with arrow functions. You're trying to assign a value to an identifier you haven't declared anywhere.

This:

```
goBack = () => {
    // do stuff
}
```

assigns an arrow function to the **already declared** identifier `goBack`. (Or, if this were within a `class`, it would create a new property and assigns the arrow function to it — but we know you're not doing this in a class, beacuse your `const` version would fail if you were.)

It's exactly like:

```
answer = 42;
```

If `answer` isn't declared, you get an error from TypeScript.

This:

```
const goBack = () => {
    // do stuff
}
```

creates a **local variable** (well, constant) and assigns the arrow function to it, just like:

```
const answer = 42;
```

---

It's useful to remember that arrow functions have no *declaration* syntax. An arrow function is always an expression. The part to the left of the `=` in your examples isn't part of that arrow function expression (although, somewhat surprisingly, it can [have an effect on the function that's created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015/37488652#37488652)).

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks! So what's better ? function goBack() or const goBack = () => {}

Comment: @Cracky - Either, depending on various things. Do you need it to close over `this`? Use an arrow function. Do you need it to be fully hoisted? Use a traditional `function` declaration. Do you want to find it by searching for `function goBack` in your code? Use a traditional function. Are you going to use `new` with it? Use `class` or a `function`. If you don't care about `this` or hoisting and you're not going to use `new` with it, it's a matter of style whether you use an arrow function or a traditional function.