# I don't understand why a certain arrow function in JavaScript doesnt behave like a regular one

Tags: javascript

The following code worked, and should print the sum of all args:

```js
const s = [5, 7, 2];
const sum = function() {
  return function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  };
}();

console.log(sum(1, 2, 4, 9)) //prints 16 as expected
```

The arrow function method that didn't work:

```js
const s = [5, 7, 2];
const sum = () => sum(...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(sum(1, 2, 4, 9))
```

This result in an error:

> SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token, expected ";" (4:26) (/index.js:4)

Why does this result in an error?

Comment: `sum(...args)` - not valid, you need `(...args)`

Comment: I don't quite understand why the original function has to be an IIFE. Why can't it just be `function sum(...args){
        return args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions can never be *named*, like you do with

```
return function sum(
```

They can be *assigned to a variable*, like

```
const fnName = (...args) => ...
```

in which case the identifier `fnName` will refer to that arrow function, but the arrow function itself won't (and can't) have a name that becomes an identifier inside the function. In contrast, a full `function` *can* have a name, which is what you're doing in the original code with the

```
return function sum(...args){
//              ^^^
```

line.

Change

```
const sum=()=>sum(...args)=>args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
```

to

```
const sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

```js
const sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
const s = [5, 7, 2];

console.log(sum(1, 2, 4, 9))
```

With function expressions, the function name usually only really matters when you want to reference the function inside itself, without having a standalone outside variable to refer to, eg:

```js
(function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
})();
```

This situation is pretty rare, but the technique used above couldn't be done with an arrow function, because arrow functions can't be named - you'd have to save a reference to the function in an identifier first:

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('foo');
  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
};
foo();
```

A function name puts the function's name into the Lexical Environment (scope chain) that the inside of the function can see.

Comment: Note that on the right-hand side of assignment expressions, arrow functions *do* get names.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652.

Comment: the function that you told me to swap gave the following error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'sum' before initialization (/index.js:8)

Comment: @JhonathanMizrahi Your `function` example is creating a function (which is immediately invoked) which returns a function. Not sure what the point of that immediate invocation is - you can either remove it entirely (and just have it be a function of `(...args)`, or if you want the arrow function to also be immediately callable to return a function of `(...args)`, do `const sum = (() => (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b))();` (but that's quite weird, it doesn't accomplish anything)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your outer arrow function are this:

`sum(...args)=>args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);`

This isn't valid: Arrow function expressions can't be named like function expressions, they can only be assigned to a variable. The interpreter reads the above code as trying to call the outer `sum()` function and then has no idea what to do with the `=>` following a function call.

Your inner function doesn't need to be named anyway. The original working version has `return function sum(...args) { ... }` but it would work exactly the same with just `return function(...args) { ... }`. Since there's no difference, you can simplify the arrow function to this as well:

```js
const sum=(()=>(...args)=>args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b))();

console.log(sum(1,2,4,9));
```

Note that the `function` keyword snippet in your question is actually an IIFE, but your arrow function snippet is a function returning a function (`sum` will return a function instead of a sum): In the stack snippet above I've changed the arrow function implementation to also be an IIFE.

Comment: Note that the original function is actually an IIFE.  there is no reason for `sum = () => (...args) => ...`.  Instead the equivalent is just `sum = (...args) => ...`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Completely missed that. Updated the answer, thanks.