# How can I add a console log in this function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Pretty straight forward question, I'm just trying to get a console log in this es6 function.

```
const testLinesSelector = state => state.tests.testLines || [];
```

I've tried:

```
const testLinesSelector = state => { 
  console.log('INSIDE THE SELECTOR ===> ');
  return {state.tests.testLines || [] }
};
```

Comment: Remove the brackets inside your return statement.

Comment: `const testLinesSelector = state => console.log('INSIDE THE SELECTOR ===> ') || state.tests.testLines || [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the braces in your `return` statement, like so:

```
const testLinesSelector = state => { 
  console.log('INSIDE THE SELECTOR ===> ');
  return state.tests.testLines || [];
};
```

As a side-note, I noticed a lot of ES6 code uses function-variables or function-properties instead of just functions - is there a reason you don’t do this instead?

```
function testLinesSelector( state ) { 
  console.log('INSIDE THE SELECTOR ===> ');
  return state.tests.testLines || [];
};
```

Comment: There are established patterns in the code base and this is the format they're expecting it to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you might consider automating your code using `Function.name` - though this requires using a named function (a la `function foobar() { ... }`). [There are techniques to get the "name" of an anonymous function or arrow-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015) in JavaScript but they're more involved and may not be compatible with the "established patterns in the code" you're working with.

But here's how you can do it with named functions:

```
function annotate( func ) {
    return ( ...args ) => {
        console.log( func.name ); // `Function.name` is supported in ES6.
        return func( ...args );
    };
}

const testLinesSelector = annotate( function testLinesSelector( state ) { return state.tests.testLines || [] } );
```