# How can i track anonymous functions in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, anonymous-function

I would like to know how I could keep track of the anonymous functions in performance. How do I know which piece of code an anonymous function is linked to?
For example, this is my code:

```
<button (click)="startTimeout()">Start timer</button>*

app.component.ts:

*...

  public startTimeout() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onStartTimeoutTimer();
    }, 1000);
  }

  private onStartTimeoutTimer(): void {
    const x = 1;
  }

...
```

And if i record my app, and i click on the button:

I can see at 2491.40 the function startTimeout
[image: I can see at 2491.40 the function startTimeout]

And 1 second after the function anonymous: onStartTimeoutTimer
[image: 1 second after the function anonymous: onStartTimeoutTimer]

But in this case I know that the anonymous function is onStartTimeoutTimer, but in general, is there a way to undarstand where the anonymous functions are generated?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are really anonaymous as in your code, I think you'll struggle to differentiate them from each other. If you're going to want to do that kind of measurement, you may want to ensure your functions have names. In your example, there are at least two ways:

```
// `Function.prototype.bind` with a named function expression¹:
public startTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function timerCallback() {
        this.onStartTimeoutTimer();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}

// Assigning to a constant/variable
public startTimeout() {
    const timerCallback = () => {
        this.onStartTimeoutTimer();
    };
    setTimeout(timerCallback, 1000);
}
```

(That second example [really does give the arrow function a name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015/37488652#37488652).)

---

¹ *Many, many years ago named function expressions got a bad rep because of bugs in multiple JavaScript engines. Those engines have **long** since been fixed.*

Comment: Good morning, above all, thanks for the answer. But I don't know if my question was clear. My goal is to see the onStartTimeoutTimer function in performance. I tried both solutions you proposed, but I didn't get the desired result. However I noticed that if in the onStartTimeoutTimer function I insert for example a console.log (), then I see this function in performance. How come?

Comment: @NicolòBracchi - Perhaps something is minifying the name away when there's no seeming debug code? I'd look in the brouwser debugger/sources tab to see what's actually being run.

Comment: @NicolòBracchi - Or actually: Could it be that it's just so fast that it's so far down in the performance list that you can't easily find it?