# How to annotate names to arrow functions in VSCode/JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, arrow-functions

When using arrow functions (e.g. on document elements event handlers), they are labeled after the event handler name in the VS Code outline.
[image]

Since I have quite a lot of them, the outline is little helpful quickly navigating to a certain one.

How to annotate a name for such arrow functions?

Using JSDoc works fine for params descriptions, but I haven't figurend out how to add a name. I'd expect the `@function` tag to do so, but it doesn't. :(

```js
/**
 * @function onMyButtonClick
 * @param {Event} event Triggering event.
 */
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = (event) => { /* my function */ };
```

Using a function assignment instead of an arrow function looks good in the outline, but (unneccessary to mention) it is *not* the same as an arrow function (e.g. the `this` context get lost). So this is NOT a solution.

```js
/**
 * @param {Event} event Triggering event.
 */
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function onMyButtonClick (event) { /* my function */ };
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@name`? https://jsdoc.app/tags-name.html

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977525/how-do-i-write-a-named-arrow-function-in-es2015) help you ?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski: Yes, I've triey `@name` and `@alias`, too. Neither did work.

Comment: What about declaring arrow function in a different line?

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat: Thanks, that gave me a better understanding of arrow functions as an assignment to a property - `onclick` in my example, so it's logical that the name of the function is "onclick" since this is where it's assigned to. JS knows of chained assignments, so I can use `let onMyButtonClick = document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = (event) => { /* my function */ };` which shows in the outline a variable `onMyButtonClick` with a nested function `onclick`. Not that nice as I whished for, but probably the closest to get to.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution doesn't work in all cases, like some arrow function cases.

The alternative is to inline a `@type`.

For example:

```js
const result = obj.someMethodWithCallback((/** @type {Event} */ event) => {
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally figured it out. It has to be a chained assignment:

```js
/**
 * @param {Event} event Triggering event.
 */
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = onMyButtonClick = (event) => { /* my function */ };
```

That way, the outline shows just the function name ("onMyButtonClick") as a function - just as desired