# how can I get the output of prototype correctly

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

I am learning JS prototype, and I got the following code, all is clear except the output of `console.log(myObj.name)`. How come it gives the name of the object itself, which is `myObj`? Doesn't it need to find the prototype from its upper-level object?

```
const myObj = function () {}

myObj.prototype.name = 'prototype.name'

myObj1 = new myObj()

console.log(myObj.name) // => myObj
console.log(myObj1.name) // => 'prototype.name'
console.log(myObj.prototype.name) // => prototype.name
```

I was expecting the same output as `myObj1` and their prototype.

Comment: `myObj` is a function. Every function has a (possibly) empty `name` property that contains its name: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myObj, 'name')`. This has nothing to do whatsoever with `myObj.prototype.name`. `myObj.prototype` is only involved when working with *instances of* `myObj`, such as `myObj1` in your example. *"I was expecting the same output as myObj1 and their prototype."* Then your expectation is wrong. `myObj` and `myObj1` are two different objects with different prototype chains.

Comment: Take a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488652/5089567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.prototype` is **not** the same as the prototype.

When you use the `new` operator, the prototype of the object being created is set to the `.prototype` attribute of the constructor function. So, when `myObj1` is created, its prototype is `myObj.prototype` and contains a `.name` attribute. Now, `myObj1` has `.name` in its prototype chain, but `myObj` doesn't; it has the attribute `.prototype.name`. See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description) for more.

Look at this for an example:

```js
const a = function() {}
a.prototype.greeting = "Hello";

const b = new a();

console.log(a.greeting);
console.log(b.greeting);
console.log(a.prototype.greeting);
```

However, the `.name` attribute is special in your case. As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) pointed out in the comments of the question, `myObj` is a function, and every function has a special `.name` attribute that contains the name of the function (ie: `'myObj'`). So, you are being confused because `myObj.name` is a completely separate thing from `myObj.prototype.name` and `myObj1.name`, which are the same.

Comment: With your example, I see where the problem is. Thank you. I still need to work on the subtle concepts of JS.

Comment: @ZweiWang No problem. `.prototype` vs the prototype is can be confusing to even more seasoned programmers. IMO, whoever made the standards should have named it something else.

Comment: If you want to get the actual prototype use `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)`

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't it need to find the prototype from its upper-level object?

Assuming you know about prototypal inheritance and that in JS, object derives from another object (unlike class based inheritance), I think what you call `upper-level` object is the prototype.

When a function is used as a constructor to create an object, in your case `myObj1`, that object derives from the object referenced by the `prototype` property of that function. Here `myObj1` derives from `myObj.prototype`. So, when you read a property `myObj1.X` and that property does not exist, runtime will go up the derivation tree and look for `myObj.prototype.X`.

However, `myObj` itself is a `function` (and also an object). All functions derive from built-in `Function.prototype`. For example,

```js
Function.prototype.myprop = 'somevalue'; //Note: not a good practice to modify Function.prototype, this is just for demo

let myObj = function() {}  // myObj derives from Function.prototype

console.log(myObj.myprop); // => somevalue
```

In your case however, `myObj.name` really actually refers to `Function.prototype.name`, which is JS built-in property and [is readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).